# Calling a servlet from JSP file on page load

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, onload

Can I call a servlet from JSP file without using a HTML form?

For example, to show results from database in a HTML table during page load.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`doGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method of the servlet to **preprocess** a request and forward the request to the JSP. Then just point the servlet URL instead of JSP URL in links and browser address bar.

E.g.

```
@WebServlet("/products")
public class ProductsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ProductService productService;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Product> products = productService.list();
        request.setAttribute("products", products);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.name}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Note that the JSP file is placed inside `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent users from accessing it directly without calling the servlet.

Also note that `@WebServlet` is only available since Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, etc), see also [@WebServlet annotation with Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7). If you can't upgrade, or when you for some reason need to use a `web.xml` which is not compatible with Servlet 3.0, then you'd need to manually register the servlet the old fashioned way in `web.xml` as below instead of using the annotation:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>productsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ProductsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>productsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/products</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Once having properly registered the servlet by annotation or XML, now you can open it by http://localhost:8080/context/products where `/context` is the webapp's deployed context path and `/products` is the servlet's URL pattern. If you happen to have any HTML `<form>` inside it, then just let it POST to the current URL like so `<form method="post">` and add a [`doPost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) to the very same servlet to perform the postprocessing job. Continue the below links for more concrete examples on that.

#### See also

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

Comment: Question is for calling Servlet from JSP. You have answered for calling JSP from servlet.

Comment: ...which is the normal practice for the functional requirement the OP had in mind.

Comment: how can you be so certain of what the OP was thinking?

Comment: *"without using a HTML form"*, so he want to preprocess the request instead of postprocessing it.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to use RequestDispatcher's Methods forward/include depending on your requirement to achieve same.

In JSP you need to use following tags:

[jsp:include](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) :

> The  element allows you
>   to include either a static or dynamic
>   file in a JSP file. The results of
>   including static and dynamic files are
>   quite different. If the file is
>   static, its content is included in the
>   calling JSP file. If the file is
>   dynamic, it acts on a request and
>   sends back a result that is included
>   in the JSP page. When the include
>   action is finished, the JSP container
>   continues processing the remainder of
>   the JSP file.

e.g.

```
<jsp:include page="/HandlerServlet" flush="true">
```

[jsp:forward](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1110.html) :

> The  element forwards the
>   request object containing the client
>   request information from one JSP file
>   to another file. The target file can
>   be an HTML file, another JSP file, or
>   a servlet, as long as it is in the
>   same application context as the
>   forwarding JSP file. The lines in the
>   source JSP file after the
>    element are not
>   processed.

e.g.

```
<jsp:forward page="/servlet/ServletCallingJsp" />
```

Check Advanced JSP Sample : JSP-Servlet Communication:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsps/ojsp/jspservlet.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, simply include it in your `action` in the `form`. But you have to write the correct `doPost` or `doGet` to handle the request!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a particular servlet method than you also use Expression Language. For example, you can do something like:

**Servlet**

```
ForexTest forexObject = new ForexTest();
request.setAttribute("forex", forexObject);
```

**JSP**

```
<body bgcolor="#D2E9FF">
Current date : ${forex.rate}
</body>
```

Comment: Note, your answer is a bit misleading, it is implying that `ForexTest` needs to be a servlet, but it doesn't necessarily need to be a servlet at all. The normal approach is that it's a Javabean and that those `get` methods should **only** be called to access properties, not to execute business logic.