# Custom Tree Taglib on Tomcat 6&7: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, taglib

I am using a custom [Tree Tag library](http://www.jenkov.com/prizetags/index.html) to display hierarchical data by using the JSP taglib mechanism. My Tomcat setup has successfully deployed other webs apps including JSP & servlet samples, but it's giving me issues with this tag library. I have found this very same problem in a number of places but without responses. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The tag library is declared as follows:

```
 1:     <%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/treetag.tld" prefix="tree" %>
```

I've reduced my usage of this library to a single line for debugging purposes and that's the code at line 20. Here's the error message:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /hello.jsp
ITree cannot be resolved to a type
20:     <% ITree tree = new Tree(); %>
```

From the above error, it looks like the server cannot find the library (jenkov-prizetags-3.4.0.jar) that I placed at *webapp*/WEB-INF/lib. I have unpacked the jar file and found the very same classes that the server cannot find, so I am inclined to think that it is just not looking in the  *webapp*/WEB-INF/lib. Am I missing something here?

Programming Environment:

- Tomcat 6&7 - same problem.
- Java SDK 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taglibs and *scriptlets* doesn't work together. You normally use the one or the other, not both.

As to the compilation error in your *scriptlet*, you just need to import the `ITree` class like as you would do in a normal Java class.

```
<%@page import="com.example.ITree" %>
```

Or, better yet, don't use *scriptlets* at all. That Java code belongs in a Java class, not a JSP file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just started playing around with Tomcat and JSPs and, on top of that, I'm using a custom taglib. I'd figured the tag lib descriptor file (*.tld), which ties the tags to their classes, would do the importing. But if what you say is true, then it would explain the unexplainable errors I have been getting.

Comment: I warmly recommend to read tutorials/books which are not written before 2001, when JSP 2.0 was introduced. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info

Comment: Thanks, I imported the necessary libraries and the problem was solved. I need to read more on why scriptlets are discouraged, but they'll do for my dev phase. If I follow correctly, all the code would go into a Java class which I would then import? Thanks.

Comment: That kind of job should be done by a servlet, in the `doGet()` method. To learn more about servlets, check our servlets wiki page: [stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). To learn about discouragement of scriptlets, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202), it comes with examples of normal approaches as well.

Comment: @BalusC So I completely got rid of scriplets in my jsp file storing the Tree Model written in pure Java code in a servlet. To construct the tree model, however, I have to invoke the servlet and then access my jsp page. How can I get the jsp to invoke the servlet? Without using scriplets, of course. I felt this was too much of a follow up to be a stand-alone question.

Comment: @BalusC Nevermind, looks like you've actually answered the same exact [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3590961/558732) before.

Comment: Yes, it's covered by the two links as well which I posted in my previous comment.