# @WebServlet annotation with Tomcat 7

Tags: servlets, annotations, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

In my application, I had a servlet which was defined like this in the *web.xml*:

```xml
<servlet>
    <display-name>Notification Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>NotificationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.XXX.servlet.NotificationServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NotificationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/notification/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After moving to use Tomcat 7, I would like to use the `@WebServlet` annotation that will do the job.
Here is the way I did it:

```
@WebServlet( name="NotificationServlet", displayName="Notification Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/notification"}, loadOnStartup=1)
public class NotificationServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

And it does not work.
Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: I was able to get rid of *so much* boilerplate XML because of this question.  Hooray for annotations!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Provided that you're sure that you're using Tomcat 7 or newer, the webapp's `web.xml` has to be declared conform Servlet 3.0 spec in order to get Tomcat to scan and process the annotations. Otherwise Tomcat will still run in a fallback modus matching the Servlet version in `web.xml`. The support for servlet API annotations was only added in Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7).

So, the root declaration of your `web.xml` must look like below (make sure you remove any `DOCTYPE` from `web.xml` too, otherwise it will still be interpreted as Servlet 2.3!).

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Further, there's a minor difference in the URL pattern. The URL pattern `/notifications` will let the servlet only listen on requests on exactly that path. It does not kick in on requests with an extra path like `/notifications/list` or something. The URL pattern `/notifications/*` will let the servlet listen on requests with extra path info as well.

The minimum `@WebServlet` annotation should thus look like this

```
@WebServlet("/notifications/*")
```

The rest of attributes are optional and thus not mandatory to get the servlet to function equally.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: You may need to add `<web-app (...) metadata-complete="false"></webapp>`.

Comment: One doesn't have to use `web.xml` at all when using `@WebServlet` annotation. It works without `web.xml`.

Comment: @destan: that's correct. However, if you have one, as in OP's case, it must be at least 3.0. You eventually need one because not everything can be annotated.

Comment: @BalusC but on servlet wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet it showing support from version 2.5. Although I tested its not working with version 2.5 it requires version 3.0. But i am little bit confused after reading servlet wiki page

Comment: @Aniket: So you say that information on Wikipedia is more reliable than the information in Oracle's own Servlet specification document? Why exactly?

Comment: I had the strange effect that the servlet worked when it was just changed, compiled and redeployed to glassfish 4. When I recompiled again without changes, and deployed, it did not work. I added the metadata-complete="false" attribute and minimized the webservlet-annotation, and now it works. Other servlets were working the whole time though.

Answer (score 6):

One may also want to check for having two classes with an annotations with the same name:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "Foo", urlPatterns = {"/foo"})
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    //...
}
```

And:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "Foo", urlPatterns = {"/bar"})
public class Bar extends HttpServlet {
    //...
}
```

In this cases, one of the servlets will not work. If you don't use the name, leave it out, like @BalusC suggests. I got the strange behavior that one of the servlets only worked right after changing and compiling it, but not after compilation without changes.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, in order to use these annotations and compile your code you must import the corresponding dependency in your pom.xml, but as provided cause your "Servlet 3.0" compliant server already has this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```