# Tomcat 6 Servlet not detected

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

Ok, This should be basic, and I have used servlets many times before via eclipse and weblogic and no problems. However with Tomcat 6 I am having issue with Servlet mapping.

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5"> 

    <description>
      Servlet and JSP Examples.
    </description>
    <display-name>Servlet and JSP Examples</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldExample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorldExample</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldExample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorldExample</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My web.xml is located in my WEB-INF folder, my servlet HelloWorldExample.class is located in WEB-INF/classes/

They are all located in tomcat/webapps/ch1/

As far as I can see it is all ok, however after hours of trial and error and multiple restarts i am still getting:

> type Status report
>
> message /ch1/HelloWorldExample
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

```
http://localhost:8080/ch1/HelloWorldExample
```

screen shot of directory structure

[image: folders]

If someone could point out where I am making an error I would be eternally grateful :)

Comment: Can you access to any JSP in your war after deploying it into tomcat?

Comment: why your servlet class havenot package?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza its not a war file. I am doing it manually. Its works file through Eclipe

Comment: @Jason It is using the default package. I am just testing. A package isn't required. It should default to classes root directory if no package is specified

Comment: put simple html welcome file in ch1/ to make sure app is recognized

Comment: @JIV I did that and it works fine. JSP and HTML work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [build and export a WAR file](http://clean-clouds.com/2012/08/15/how-to-export-war-file-from-eclipse-to-tomcat/) and deploy it on Tomcat, then it will automatically go on the right place. Also, pay attention on this part of your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorldExample</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Servlet-class needs to be fully qualified class name, that is: **your.package.classname** (ignore if you are using default package, which is a bad practice generally). When you deal with this problem, I would suggest that you install Tomcat 7 and take advantage of Servlet 3.0 benefits, i.e. get rid of web.xml configuration and use servlet annotations. More info:

- [Servlet 3.0 annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)
- [@WebServlet annotation with tomcat7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat7)

Comment: I agree packaging is best, but this is test and should work like this. Also annotaion and 3.0 is great,however the system I have use is 2.5 only. Hence the web.xml

Comment: @Rhys I understand. However, as I suggested, package your project into war and deploy it - it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I just deployed to war, Added to webapps root and restarted and no luck there either. I think my tomcat installation is faulty

Comment: @Rhys How did you deploy it? Using Tomcat Web console (usually, http://localhost:8080/manager) or manually copying/extracting? I would strongly suggest first approach.

Comment: it ended up being the fact that I compiled it with 1.6 and java_home is version 1.7. All working now. CHeers.

Answer (score 2):

You should put folder "ch1" under **tomcat/webapps**, not under tomcat/webapps/ROOT.

Follow this folder structure:

```
tomcat：
--webapps
----ch1
--------META-INF
--------WEB-INF
----------classes
----------lib
----------web.xml
```

Comment: I have tried that. But still the same results. What URL would you suggest that I use?

Comment: Can you post your folders structure ?

Comment: Are you sure web.xml is under META-INF, I think it is suppose to be under WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

Your `ch1` folder should be under `webapps` not under `webapps/ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

please move the ch1 folder to `webapps` from `webapps/ROOT`
And remember to `restart the Tomcat Server` after this change