# How to map a servlet call from a JSP page using form action?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page named Welcome_2.html [image: HTML page directory]and in its form action I have invoked a servlet like this :

```
<form action="/servlets/MyFirstServlet" method="post" id="form_id">
```

The servlet "MyFirstServlet" is under [image: servlet directory]
     WEB-INF
     classes
     servlets
     MyFirstServlet

and the jsp is under the folder
     HTML 
which is in the same level like WEB-INF

i.e. inside practice I have 3 folders[image: project structure]
     HTML
     META-INF
     WEB-INF

in web.xml I have the following snippet

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.MyFirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/MyFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why the servlet is not being invoked? I am clicking on the HTML page on my browser and trying to invoke the servlet ... I am just a beginner 
pardon me for my poor intellect.

Comment: What behavior do you actually see? Do you receive a 400? For what URL?

Comment: For "   file:///C:/servlets/MyFirstServlet  " URL I am getting Web page is not found .

Comment: That is not normal. How do you access the first page on your website? The one rendered by the JSP.

Comment: You should run using this `Welcome_2.html` page on the browser , as you invoke the servlet from here

Comment: @user3655102 I am 100% sure that you are submitting the form via server.You are opening the html page in browser and hitting submit thats why `file:///` appears.

Comment: Yes ... but what is the proper way to do it?
I am a starter ... pardon me for my poor intellect

Comment: As a starter it essential to cover the basics of the [**Oracle tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/basics.html#100368) and you can start from many examples from the sites like _tutorialspoint_ and _javatpoint_

Comment: I have added the structure .. help me please

Comment: It is better if you use the IDE's for web development. either choose eclipse or netbeans. But you have many ide's in the market . but these two are widely used and are simple

Comment: ok thanks a lot add me at your gmail Id .. mine is chiranjib.nandy48@gmail.com

but what about thi sproblem how to make it work?

Comment: @user3655102 ok I have sent you a request in gmail,delete all unnecessary comments here.I will guide from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your form action is `"/servlets/First"`
so your url pattern should be

```
<url-pattern>/servlets/First</url-pattern>
```

Comment: This will also work but it makes more sense to change the form action instead of the mapping because on actual projects changing the servlet mapping can affect more components

Answer (score 7):

Change your jsp form to ,

```
<form action="/servlets/MyFirstServlet" method="post" id="form_id">
```

to match the `url` pattern in your `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/MyFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This line `<url-pattern>/servlets/MyFirstServlet</url-pattern>` refers that url's matching the pattern will invoke the `MyFirstServlet`

Read the [**Oracle Tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) before you configure your `web.xml` elements

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I changed accordingly ( and edited my post also,please see). But still it is shown web page not found .... and the URL is getting loaded as 
file:///C:/servlets/MyFirstServlet  .... Webpage is not found.

Comment: Can you post your project structure , instead of explaining it by words  ?

Comment: @user3655102 I am just thinking out loud... if you can tell the first URL you are accessing that might help.
i think you are just opening yout HTML by clicking on your HTML file instead of http://{serverURL}:{port}/{appliucation}/{myhtml.html}

Answer (score 2):

If you use tomcat 7 , you don't need to care about that. For example :

In your servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/myFirstServlet")  

public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {

   // your code 

}
```

In your html :

```
<!-- here you write myFirstServlet in the action tag -->
<form id="somethingGoesHere" action="myFirstServlet" method="post" >
```

Comment: Are you sure that `tomcat` supports annotations despite the servlets version

Comment: @sankrish: Yes, Tomcat 7 supports annotations . Read here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat7`

Answer (score 1):

Unless your app is deployed as ROOT.war, all your URLs will be relative to `http://myserver/webapp`. So my guess is that you should rather use relative URLs. As your JSP is in HTML, you would need to write:

```
<form action="../servlets/MyFirstServlet" method="post" id="form_id">
```