# Second servlet in the project not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am new to Servlets. 
I made a simple project with 2 jsp files. and two Servlers
jsp1, jsp2, servlet1 and servlet2.

When the code in both jsps' body tags is this (Both points to servlet1 )

```
<form method="post" action="servlet1">
<input type="submit">
</form>`
```

and There is a simple Sysout in the servlets' doPost method..

It works perfectly fine in this scenario.

But when I make the second jsp call servlet2. It doesn't work. It gives me this error screen

**HTTP Status 404 - /Project/servlet2 
 type Status report
 message /Project/servlet2
 description The requested resource (/Project/servlet2) is not available.
 Apache Tomcat/6.0.26**

So can't we use two different servlets in same project?

EDIT:

This is the web.xml file. As you can see. All mappings are there.

'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp1.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>servler1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>servler1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servler1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servler1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servler1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>servler2</display-name>
    <servlet-name>servler2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servler2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servler2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servler2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

'

Comment: have you added entry in web.xml

Comment: Yes, you can. Where is the code and the mapping?

Comment: Please check the question. I just edited with web.xml content. Mappings are all fine, I guess.

Comment: @Ramandeep Can you tell me your second servlet name?

Comment: I guess I found the solution but I would still need some explanation.

I made another similar project with servlets in com.Project.servlets package. 
and both JSPs in a JSP directory in WebContent. 

Web.xml has default.jsp as welcome page and that page forwards to jsp1 and hence when I call servlet1 from jsp1. It works fine. 

But when I try for jsp2 by typng the url pointing to jsp2 and calling servler2 from it. It cannot find it as it is searching it in JSP directory only. 

So when I change the action attribute to "../Servlet2" It works. So it has something to do with JSP forward tag.

Comment: Now I have serched about JSP forward tag. It sounded to me like Server.transfer (in ASP- I used to code in ASP earlier) i.e Client is never informed about the transfer to another page. But I still cannot understand how it impacted here. I would be glad if someone could explain to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am agree with the answer of @San Krish. But little more explanation.

As you said:

> Second servlet in the project not working.

*You need to map every servlet in `web.xml` file like you are mapping first servlet.*

**EDITED:**

From your edited question. you are using `servler1` in your `web.xml` file but in jsp using `servlet1` so this is the main issue. So use `servler1` in your jsp file.

Eg:

```
<form method="post" action="servler1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>`
```

**EDITED1:**
There may be another reason.

If your second servlet is inside package you must be included package name also in `web.xml`. Suppose your second servlet `servlet2.java` inside `com.myproject.test` package you need to do like following in web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>servler2</display-name>
    <servlet-name>servler2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.test.servlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servler2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servler2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Sorry, That's just a typo in the question. It is "servler1" in JSP too.

Answer (score 2):

You might not have mapped the second servlet in the `WEB.XML`. Check for the entry else create your own like ,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Second</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>path.SecondServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Second</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SecondServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Check what [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) says before configuring your `web.xml`

Also read my answer on this [How to map a servlet call from a JSP page using form action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751965/how-to-map-a-servlet-call-from-a-jsp-page-using-form-action/23752007#23752007)

Update :

Your 2.jsp should map the `action` attribute as ,

```
<form action="./servler2" method="post">
```

Comment: I updated the question with the web.xml content. As you can see, The mappings are fine.

Comment: Can you show your jsp from which you are calling the 2nd servlet.check to my update in the answer