# Tomcat 7.0: Requested Resource (Servlet) not available

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm desperately trying to execute a Servlet from an HTML action form and getting the following error message:

> **HTTP Status 404** - /WSE_Web/QueryServlet
>
> **type:** Status report
>
> **message:** /WSE_Web/QueryServlet
>
> **description:** The requested resource (/WSE_Web/QueryServlet) is not available.

I looked through several questions here and tutorials but I cannot find what I'm missing (also I'm not very familiar with Servlets and Web Programming).
I'm using Eclipse with Tomcat 7.0.12.

My Action form:

[image]

My Servlet class:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/QueryServlet")
public class QueryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WSE_Web</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: Try changing the action to `/QueryServlet` with a slash.

Comment: Look at   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat7

Comment: Not sure it is correct to make reference to http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd **and** http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd on the same `web.xml` file.  Is this correct?.  AFAIK, You need to stick to 3.0 for tomcat to know and process your annotations

Answer (score 0):

If your application context is `/WSE_Web` your application is right and should work.

But if `/WSE_Web` is not your application context change url-pattern to:

```
@WebServlet("/WSE_Web/QueryServlet")
```

To be sure you also can use web.xml file:

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.QueryServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/QueryServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: My HTML page is running at http://localhost:8080/WSE_Web/ and when clicking the action form I'm hitting http://localhost:8080/WSE_Web/QueryServlet so everything should be fine.

Comment: @FrankWittich: Did you try `/WSE_Web/QueryServlet` instead of `/QueryServlet`?

Comment: Yeah, didn't help unfortunately. The result is always the same.

Comment: @FrankWittich: Try web.xml way. I'va edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what change did it but now it works. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @FrankWittich: Yeah, your code should works. I'm glad your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to you have proper html:

```
<input type='text' name='query' size='96'/><!-- your missing the `/` at the end -->
<input type='submit' name='subButton' value='Search!'/><!-- your missing the `/` at the end -->
```

Also change the method value to `get`, since you are overriding only `doGet()`

```
<form method='get' action='QueryServlet'>
...
</form>
```