# javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089 exception In servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet called `Document` to which I want to redirect all requests starting with `Document` something like

```
http://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/Document/abcdwcklsclds
```

should be redirected to servlet Document. 
So, I used an annotation like this :

```
@WebServlet("/Document/*")
```

However, for some unidentified reason, it  gives an exception that says:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: AS-WEB-CORE-00089
```

This exception is in Document.java is thrown as soon as I call

request.getRequestDispatched("main.html").forward(request, response) .
otherwise no exception.

however, With same request in other servlets, main.html gets called just fine.

Comment: As already said in your previous question, please show stack trace,  relevant parts of the servlet : the class declaration including annotations and the method containing the `forward`, and the type and version of servlet container (Tomcat, Glassfish, ...)

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Here is what I realized.The error is because I have request.getRequestDispatcher.forward("main.html") statement in doGet method of Document.java and problem is that for some reason statements in doGet  gets called over and over when we have RequestDispatcher in there .Last time it was 17 times , because of which we are getting this error. Could you help me out with possible reasons,please ?

Comment: Without the elements I asked I cannot say more : if it is still same problem, it is caused by the forward calling the current servlet what gives an infinite loop.

Comment: and I forgot to mention that I am using Glassfish. But, I am not really calling the current servlet but an html file.

Comment: I first thought of a typo, but it is the real reason. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `forward` and a `redirect` are **not** the same thing. A redirect allows you to go to any URL, eventually on another server or with another protocol, because you ask the client to query that URL.

In a forward you ask the servlet container to pass the control to another servlet of the same application (inside same context). As you use a relative path you are actually requesting what is the servlet for : `http://host.do.main/appname/Document/main.html` because the relative URL is added at the end of the address of current page (it could even be `.../Document/.../main.html`) !

And **you** declared that any page under `/Document` should be served by the `Document` servlet ... so the infinite loop ...

You can fix it two ways :

- if you really need to use relative paths (it is inherently dangerous but you might have reasons to do it), try `../main.html` if called from `/Document` or `../../main.html` if called from `/Document/something`
- use an absolute path :

  ```
  contextPath = request.getContextPath();
  request.getRequestDispatcher(contextPath + "/main.html").forward(request, response)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The Filter looks right.

Are you using `Servlets 3.0` and no older version? In older versions you would have to edit the `web.xml`. And in 3.0 it would have to look like in this  [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559478/4349288)

Does `Document` extend `HttpServlet`?

Could you show us some more of your Code, maybe then it would be easier to see what's going wrong.

Greetings