# Java Servlet JSP does not print out attribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to write a servlet using generated HTML code, rather then printing out static HTMLs.

I'm using Eclipse-EE Europa and Tomcat 6.

I tried to use the flowing tips from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370960/generate-an-html-response-in-a-java-servlet)

But instead of printing the desired attribute It seems that the jsp ignoring the attribute or the attribute is empty.

Here is the servlet:

```
package com.serv.pac;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class for Servlet: testServlet
 *
 */
 public class testServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public testServlet() {
        super();
    }       

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String message = "doGet response";

        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/testServlet/WEB-INF/index1.jsp").forward(request, response);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("the servlet");
    }   

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("first servlet");
    }               
}
```

Here is the JSP

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2370960</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>Message: ${message}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following is the :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>servlet1_test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>index1.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>testServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.serv.pac.testServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And that is what I'm getting in the browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2370960</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>Message: </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As one may see there is nothing after the "Message" in the html body, as if the message attribute is empty.

Thank You

Comment: Your request dispatcher should probably be `getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index1.jsp")` assuming regular directory structure. Can you show yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see this happenning is you aren't actually accessing your `Servlet`.

You've declared a `<welcome-file>`

```
<welcome-file>index1.jsp</welcome-file>
```

So if you try to hit

`localhost:8080/YourContextPath`

the default `Servlet` will render and send you that jsp with a missing `message` attribute.

If you want to hit your actual `Servlet`, you need to use

`localhost:8080/YourContextPath/testServlet`

Note that you need to change

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/testServlet/WEB-INF/index1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and **move your file under `WEB-INF`.**