# Java Servlet looping when forwarded to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to convert a Java class to be displayed on a web page. Using the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370960/generate-an-html-response-in-a-java-servlet) as a guideline. The Java does what it's supposed to if I print everything out with `System.out`. When trying to forward to a jsp page, it loops (re-instantiates?), and doesn't stop (have to manually kill the process).

Connector.java

```
public class Connector extends HttpServlet {
    private static URL url = https://my.server.com/WEB-INF/ws/service.php?wsdl");;
    private static final String USERNAME = "JoeBoB";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "1337pass";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        //login to my.server.com
        try {
          authToken = serverAPI.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
          System.out.println("Logged into server with Token: " + authToken);
          //this shows up in console over and over again, until manually killed
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("message","bacon");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/draw.jsp").forward(request, response);
        //line above appears to be the one that re-inits the class. 
        //commenting this out stops the looping
        //but also prevents the data from showing on the webpage
        serverAPI.logout(authToken);
```

WEB-INF/draw.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>This is my drawn page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Connector</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Connector</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.package.Connector</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Connector</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have a feeling it's somewhat simple (something I forgot to configure, or misconfigured), but for the life of me can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mapping /* to your servlet you are overriding the default handler for JSP requests. You need to use a more specific pattern, using a file extension or subdirectory.

Comment: I had just figured that out on my own and was coming back to let others now.  What I did was change the `url-pattern` in web.xml to point to index.jsp - which fires off the java and then points back to draw.jsp