# Unable to compile the class for JSP in tomcat 8.5.95

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a project "Expense Tracker" .This is my second project, Im Stuck with this error.

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

### Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: \[1\] in the generated java file: \[E:\\ECLIPSE.metadata.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp3\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\OnlineExpenseManager\\org\\apache\\jsp\\index_jsp.java\]
The type org.hibernate.SessionFactory cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: \[15\] in the generated java file: \[E:\\ECLIPSE.metadata.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tmp3\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\OnlineExpenseManager\\org\\apache\\jsp\\index_jsp.java\]
Only a type can be imported. org.hibernate.SessionFactory resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: \[17\] in the jsp file: \[/index.jsp\]
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
14:     \<%@include file="component/NavBar.jsp" %\>
15:
16:     \<%
17:     SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
18:     out.print(factory);
19:     %\>
20:

An error occurred at line: \[17\] in the jsp file: \[/index.jsp\]
The method getSessionFactory() from the type HibernateUtil refers to the missing type SessionFactory
14:     \<%@include file="component/NavBar.jsp" %\>
15:
16:     \<%
17:     SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
18:     out.print(factory);
19:     %\>
20:
```

### Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:214)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:600)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:381)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:597)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:383)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:331)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:583)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

This is my hibernate class:

```
package com.db;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import com.entity.User;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            Properties properties =new Properties();
            properties.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expense_tracker_db");
            properties.put(Environment.USER, "root");
            properties.put(Environment.PASS, "MyNewPass");
            properties.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            properties.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
            properties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);     
            properties.put(Environment.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, true);
            properties.put(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory");
            
            configuration.setProperties(properties);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
            
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            
            sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            
        }
        return sessionFactory;
        
    }

}
```

This is my index file

```
<%@page import="com.db.HibernateUtil "%>
<%@ page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<%@include file="component/all_css.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
    <%@include file="component/NavBar.jsp" %>

    <%
    SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    out.print(factory);
    %>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." height="670px">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."height="670px">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."height="670px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the tomcat server version

Comment: Why did you try to change a Tomcat version? What version of Tomcat did you use?

Comment: Putting Java code in a normal Java class instead of a JSP file will give much better error reporting. The abovelinked duplicate shows what that would have been and how you can fix that in Eclipse project settings. After fixing that, start learning Servlets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2370960 This is the way to avoid Java code in JSP files.