# JSP in /WEB-INF returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available"

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, web-inf

I created a JSP file.

`sample.jsp`

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is jsp program
  </body>
</html>
```

I placed it here in the `samplejsp` project.

```
samplejsp
 `-- WebContent
      `-- WEB-INF
           `-- sample.jsp
```

I opened it on the following URL.

`http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/sample.jsp`

But it shows the following error in browser.

> ### 404 ERROR
>
> The requested resource (/sample.jsp) is not available.

Comment: sorry,I resolve my mistake today omwards

Comment: 7 days passed and you haven't accepted nothing since...

Answer (score 8):

404 simply means ["Not Found"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5).

Either the URL is wrong (note: case sensitive!), or the resource is not there where you think it is.

Just verify the URL and/or verify if the resource is there where you'd expect it to be. You placed `sample.jsp` in `/WEB-INF` folder. This way it is not publicly accessible without calling through a front controller servlet.

Put it outside `/WEB-INF`.

```
samplejsp
 `-- WebContent
      |-- WEB-INF
      `-- sample.jsp
```

If you want to keep it in `/WEB-INF`, then you need to create a front controller servlet which forwards to it in `doGet()` method as below.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/sample.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Finally "open" the JSP by just calling servlet's actual URL instead of JSP's fictive URL.

#### See also:

- [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application)
- [Calling servlet from JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463818/calling-servlet-from-jsp/)
- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets/)

Comment: ya i checked but it shows the above error ,Is there any error in the program

Comment: Yes, either the URL is wrong, or the resource is actually not there. The error message does not lie.

Comment: ok,i accept the error message not  lie,Ya error occurred in URL i understood that also,I selected the the jsp file and copied the URL from Properties,Then why it shows the error,How to solve this?

Comment: Hint: the URL should be an URL, not a disk file system path. If `sample.html` is at `http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/sample.html` then the `sample.jsp` is obviously at `http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/sample.jsp`. Thus the `<form action>` should be `http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/sample.jsp` or better just `sample.jsp`. In your case, this should do: `<form action="sample.jsp">`.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly related to your directory structure or packaging.
Can you please add your directory structure?
Similar to below -

```
src 
|-html\
|-jsp\
```

Perhaps this should do it

```
<form action="sample.jsp" method=get>
      <input type =submit value="submit">
</form>
```

**Edit** - WEB-INF does not allow direct access to JSP.

Comment: Quick fix - Move the HTML and JSP file from WEB-INF folder and run.

Comment: I mean move both the files from WEB-INF to some other folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my spring boot web application with JSP it didn't worked until I have added this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

even after configuring view resolver

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

If you find why this worked please comment.

Comment: tomcat-embed-jasper: provides support for .jsp file rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I had got this error- JSP file [/WEB-INF/viewshello.jsp] not found.

I have created the Jsp file hello in the view folder inside WEB-INF folder insted it can't able to find the resource.

Then I have deleted the previous "hello.jsp" file and created the new one at the same location.

And it works finally!!
May be it will work in your case also..so try it.