# Calling servlet from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Basically, I want to display the products in an ArrayList on a JSP page. I have done that in the servlet code. But theres no output.

Also Do I have to place products.jsp in the /WEB-INF folder? When I do that, I get a requested not resource error.

My Servlet Code (InventoryServlet.java)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products = Inventory.populateProducts(); // Obtain all products.
        request.setAttribute("products", products); // Store products in request scope.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/products.jsp").forward(request, response); // Forward to JSP page to display them in a HTML table.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Retrieving products failed!", ex);
    }

}
```

My JSP Page (products.jsp)

```
<h2>List of Products</h2>

<table>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
       <tr>
           <td>${product.Description}</td>
          <td>${product.UnitPrice}</td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 

 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Inventory</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.ShoppingCart.InventoryServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Inventory</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/products</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: may be you need to put the JSP **just outside** the WEB-INF

Comment: If you trace into the servlet call - are you sure that some value is being put into 'products'?

Comment: JSP can go most anywhere so long as you use the correct path to refer to them. Your compiled bits will end up under WEB-INF/ - probably as classes/ or similar

Comment: Just to make sure: you navigate to `/products`, not to `/products.jsp`, right?

Comment: Ok. Now I'm getting this error. 

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Id' not found on type com.ShoppingCart.Product

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to open the page by requesting the servlet URL instead of the JSP URL. This will call the `doGet()` method.

Placing JSP in `/WEB-INF` effectively prevents the enduser from directly opening it without involvement of the `doGet()` method of the servlet. Files in `/WEB-INF` are namely not public accessible. So if the preprocessing of the servlet is mandatory, then you need to do so. Put the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder and change the requestdispatcher to point to it.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But you need to change all existing links to point to the servlet URL instead of the JSP URL.

#### See also:

- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Ok. Now I'm getting this error. javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Id' not found on type com.ShoppingCart.Product

Comment: That's a new problem which actually deserves its own question, but ala. To fix this error, you need to ensure that you have a `getId()` method and that you access it as follows `${product.id}` (and thus **not** `${product.Id}`).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a diagram for web application folder structure. No need to place your JSPs under WEB-INF.

[image]

- debug or put print statememnts in your Servlet to make sure that the arraylist has elements in it.
- Right-click on your browser and view page source. Is there anything generated at all?

Comment: What about my java package....all the classes belong to that package. And are stored in the src folder in the main project folder.

Comment: OK so I guess you are still in your development environment and your IDE( eclipse,netbeans, Idea) is taking care of deploying web components. However, the java classes would go under WEB-INF\classes

Answer (score 1):

the difference between put a jsp file under WebRoot and WEB-INF is:
if you put under WebRoot, user can access your jsp file using the URL on the address bar of browser; if you put under WEB-INF, user can't access the file because it is hidden from public.

The only way you can access that is through Servlet using forward or redirect.