# Referencing a resource placed in WEB-INF folder in JSP file returns HTTP 404 on resource

Tags: jsp, resources, web-inf

I have a dynamic web project called BookShopWeb which I created in eclipse, with the following directory structure

```
/BookShopWeb/|
  |--src
  |---WebContent
                | 
                |---META-INF
                |----WEB-INF---web.xml
                            |
                            |--css--styles.css
                            |--jsp---index.jsp
```

In web.xml I set the start page as

```
<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

In the index.jsp I am including the css as

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" />
</head>
```

The index page when loaded however does not show the css info.I checked the element with firebug and it shows an error report

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 - Error report..
The requested resource (/css/styles.css) is not available.
```

Any idea why this occurs?How can I correct this?
thanks
mark

Answer (score 22):

Files in `/WEB-INF` folder are not public accessible. Put the CSS files one level up, in the `WebContent` folder, and ensure that they are accessible by entering their URL straight in the browser address bar. Also, the URL which you specify in the `<link href>` must be relative to the request URL (which you see in the browser address bar when opening the JSP), not to its location on the server disk file system. The best approach is to make it domain-relative by starting with a forward slash `/`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/BookShopWeb/css/styles.css" />
```

or a bit more dynamically so that you don't need to change your JSPs everytime whenever you change the context path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" />
```

JSP files can be kept in `/WEB-INF`, but this way they are only accessible through a dispatching servlet, either homegrown by extending `HttpServlet` or implicitly by the servletcontainer such as the `<welcome-file>`.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/)
- [JSP in /WEB-INF returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386031/404-error-the-requested-resource-is-not-available-even-though-i-have-web-inf)

Comment: if JSP files are kept in /WEB-INF, how should I write field in href?

Comment: @shirley: just specify URL of dispatching servlet. If you're completely new to servlets, just read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: I have the same problem. I put `css` folder in `webapp` and my `jsp` is in `WEB-INF`...I still can't get the reference to work. Is there some confifugration to make in `web.xml` servelet dispatcher for that also ?

Answer (score 6):

Your directory structure should be

```
/BookShopWeb/|
  |--src
  |---WebContent
                | 
                |---META-INF
                |----WEB-INF---web.xml
  |
  |--css--styles.css
  |--jsp---index.jsp
```

Also You named your css as styles.jsp which is not proper way to declare a css file.

In your web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

In your jsp file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: The css file was styles.css .I made mistake while typing the question.

Comment: okay. But your directory structure should be as in my answer.