# Netbeans WEB application project not able to read the relative path for CSS file

Tags: html, css, jsp, netbeans

I'm trying out example codes from a book called **"Murach's Java Servlet and JSP"** For some reason, I can't get the CSS to work. `Netbeans` doesn't seem to find the `main.css` file using a `relative href` path.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Murcah's Java Servlet and JSP</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Join our email list</h1>
        <p>To join our email list, enter your name and email address below.</p>

        <form action="emailList" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />

            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required /> <br />
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" required /> <br/>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" required /> <br />

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Join Now" id="submit" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body{
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    background-color: darkred;
    background: yellow;
}

h1{
    color:teal;
}

label{
    float:left;
    width:6em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"]{
    width: 15em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

br{
    clear:both;
}

#submit{
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/ch02email"/>
```

Here's how the resources are organized into sub-folders.

[image]

And `main.css` path I believe to be `ch02email/resources/css/main.css` But since I have set the contextPath to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/ch02email"/>
```

on **index.html** you can see that my `href` is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" type="text/css" />`

For some reason the css doesn't apply. Also, I tried to view the source to open the css but I get the ff.

[image]

**view source**[image]

**view source**I get a `404` message.

[image]

(**view source**)

I tried both on `Firefox` and `Google Chrome` but I get the same result. CSS`enter code here` file can't be found.

What am I missing here? I even tried to put `WEB-INF/resources/css/main.css` which I don't think to be right as I understand not to include `WEB-INF` when referencing.

Lastly, I tried to use `<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"/>` with no success.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: post web.xml as well

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the reason why it's not able to access the main.css file. I found the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752246/referencing-a-resource-placed-in-web-inf-folder-in-jsp-file-returns-http-404-on). I found that files contained in `WEB-INF` are not accessible publicly. So what I did was move the `resources` folder like what's on the screenshot.

[image]

`resources` folder is now contained in `Web Pages` folder.

[image]

I know this is a simple question but caused headache for that very simple detail I didn't know.

I hope this helps others who will find this post. :)