# Netbeans: Running a project on Tomcat doesn't see any network activity

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I am running tomcat 9.0.30 with openjdk version "11.0.10"

I am working on a Maven project. I can compile and build just fine. However, when I run the project on the tomcat the web application comes out looking barebones. There is no network activity going through, so it's legit just text popping up. No images, no css, no anything. Just raw html.

However, when I grab the war file that gets compiled when I build and manually run it on the tomcat server, there is no issue. My teammates however, can just run it on netbeans directly and it loads no problem. While I can get work done, it would be really helpful if I was able to have netbeans auto compile some of the changes I make, which is why I want to get it working.

I've replicated all their settings and can't figure out why netbeans won't run the project correctly for me. It's clearly compiling correctly since the war file being manually deployed works.

There are no errors being thrown in the tomcat logs or on the console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details, so that it becomes easy for someone to attempt resolving your issue? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Comment: @RishabhKumar This is legit all the details I have. I tried to be as thorough as I could, but there are no logs with errors being printed. Netbeans isn't throwing an error, I legit have no idea what's going wrong and these are all the details I have

Comment: Have you tried other threads like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400983/netbeans-web-application-project-not-able-to-read-the-relative-path-for-css-file

Comment: You can also check console logs in browser, to see for errors if any and post them here. By details I meant debugging details.