# spring MVC MAVEN: Static resource With 404

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller

I have searched for this but didn't get the solution for the same. I got information i.e. we have to use `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>` and place all the static member like css/img/js inside resources folder

```
src

|--main

|    |

|    |--java

|    |--resources

|    |--webapp
```

And then we have to use either jstl or spring tags to map the resources as below:

```
<head>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <spring:url value="/resources/LoginForm.css" var="loginCss" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${loginCss}" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I have developed some code by keeping all the points in mind but getting 404 error for static resources.

[click here for project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB5SY.jpg)

code for dispatcher servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    ">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anand" />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


</beans>
```

Code for loginform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Home-Login</title>
<spring:url value="/resources/LoginForm.css" var="loginCss" />
<spring:url value="/resources/logo1.PNG" var="logo1" />
<spring:url value="/resources/img1.png" var="img1" />
<spring:url value="/resources/img2.png" var="img2" />
<spring:url value="/resources/img3.png" var="img3" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${loginCss}" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="login">
<!-- header starts here -->
<div id="facebook-Bar">
  <div id="facebook-Frame">
    <div id="logo"> <a href="#"><img src="${logo1}" /></a></div>
    <div id="header-main-right">
      <div id="header-main-right-nav">
        <form:form action="loginform.html" method="post" commandName="loginform">
        <table border="0" style="border:none">
            <tr>
              <td ><form:input type="text" tabindex="1"  path="userName" placeholder="UserName" class="inputtext radius1" value="" /></td>
              <td ><form:input type="password" tabindex="2" path="password" placeholder="Password" class="inputtext radius1" /></td>
              <td ><input type="submit" class="fbbutton" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input id="persist_box" type="checkbox" name="persistent" />
                  <span style="color:#ccc;">Keep me logged in</span></label></td>
              <td><label><a href="" style="color:#ccc; text-decoration:none">forgot your password?</a></label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form:form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container" style="width:100%;height:80%; min-width:1000px;">

<div class="mySlides fade" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="${img1}" style="width:100%;height:100%" />
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="${img2}" style="width:100%;height:100%" />
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="${img3}" style="width:100%;height:100%" />
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br/>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When it redirects me to loginform.jsp and i do F12-->network analysis, it shows me 404 for static resources like ,img1,img2,img3,logo1 and for .css file.
[Click Here for F12 debug and chrome view of page without css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaquh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources inside WEB-INF are protected to be not accessible directly from the client.

In general, if it is static resources such as html, CSS, JavaScript can be placed outside WEB-INF. Static content placed outside can be therefore downloaded directly from the client browser.

Pls read  [Referencing a resource placed in WEB-INF folder in JSP file returns HTTP 404 on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752246/referencing-a-resource-placed-in-web-inf-folder-in-jsp-file-returns-http-404-on)

Comment: Except `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources`

Comment: @Clement...Thanks that is what exactly i did unknowingly and it is working for me as i have written in my answer but the logic behind that i got after reading your explanation... Thanks a lot..:)

Answer (score 1):

[[Solved]]: Finally solved the problem but i'm not sure the approach i have used here is correct or not but yeah it's working for me. Solution: i have copied the resources folder under webapp folder (i.e. WEB_INF & resources are siblings).

[Click here for updated directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUdMr.jpg)

Please do provide better solution of this if you have for the same: