# correct way to import CSS and JS in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have folder hierarchy like this

[image]

how to add css and js file in this index.jsp

browser developer tools

[image]

Comment: add script and css relative urls?

Comment: yes, I am confused about the path. it would be <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"> or <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: i have attached the creen shot, the css and js files are in the respective folder

Comment: @Ayush - Do you mean from within one of the .jsp files? Is it served with the `/jsp` part in the path?

Comment: Post your question **as text** (you can *also* post a picture), but you should show the hierarchy as text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: i need to import css from another foder in jsp from another folder

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the paths they will have from the *browser's* perspective. If the browser sees the hierarchy you've shown, then from any of the `.jsp` files in your `jsp` directory, you'd use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/filename.css">
```

The `..` goes up one level (from `jsp` to your root), and then `/css` goes into the `css` directory.

You *could* use root-relative URL like `/css/filename.css`, but that will break if you put this whole thing somewhere other than the root on the server.

Comment: `/css/filename.js`. JS file in `<link>`, it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `css` and `js` files inside one of the `jsp` files, add these inside `head`

**For CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/filename.css">
```

**For JS**

```
<script src="../js/filename.js"></script>
```

Here `..` represents the directory above the `jsp` (one level up) then `/js` or `/css` will goto respective directory.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752246/referencing-a-resource-placed-in-web-inf-folder-in-jsp-file-returns-http-404-on) for the correct way to organise your files in a Tomcat application.

The path to your CSS files should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: `href="./css/styles.css"` should be `href="../css/styles.css"`

Comment: See this link: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3244-non-module-file-paths-are-relative-to-the-working-directory-in-node-js.htm it depends how the application is served. Also the OP has already said that `"../css/styles.css"` doesn't work.