# JSP ask for user input and query database using sql tags

Tags: jsp, jdbc, jstl, derby, javadb

I have a jsp page where I am using sql tags to query, update, and create columns in a database. I want to ask a user for input and when they insert the input, query the database for what they input. I cannot see how to do that. How can I display and input have the user submit that input and then send that input as a query using an sql tag? I believe the users input will have to be put in the "where NAME = ''" part of the code. here is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <sql:setDataSource var="data" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
     url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testing"
     user="testing"  password="testing"/>
    </head>

    <body>


   <sql:query var="t" dataSource="$ {data}">
        SELECT NAME FROM DATA WHERE NAME = ''
    </sql:query>    



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Query the data from the database like this

```
<sql:query var="data" >
    SELECT * FROM public.DATA where NAME = ?
    <sql:param value="${param.searchString}" />
</sql:query>
```

In this case,`searchString`(which we used like `param.searchString` is our search string) will be the name of the input textbox like this

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" />
```

Then depending on your requirement you can use scoped variable `data` to show using forEach or anything else.

### See Also

- [How to use JSTL sql tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697041/how-to-use-jstl-sql-tag)

Comment: can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page