#     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

Tags: jsp, jstl

I followed the guide in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to install JSTL but I got the following error when I tried to launch my JSP page:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

The taglib declaration is:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I installed JSTL 1.1 under `/WEB-INF/lib` in Tomcat webapps and tried to do the same in my project, but it didn't work. I also tried version 1.2 of JSTL and still the same message. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator.html) class is introduced in JSP 2.0 and then later repackaged to jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator in JSP 3.0. This error can thus have the following possible causes:

- You are not running a JSP 2.0 compatible servletcontainer. For example, Tomcat 4.x or 5.0. You need a Tomcat version between 5.5 and 9.0.
- You are actually running a JSP 3.0 compatible servletcontainer (the first version with jakarta package instead of javax) such as Tomcat 10.0 or newer. In that case you'll need to upgrade JSTL from 1.x to 2.0 or newer. Installation instructions can be found in [How to install JSTL? It fails with "The absolute uri cannot be resolved" or "Unable to find taglib" or NoClassDefFoundError or ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-it-fails-with-the-absolute-uri-cannot-be-resolved-or-una).
- You have cluttered the `/WEB-INF/lib` with arbitrarily downloaded `jsp-api.jar` or `j2ee.jar` or `javaee.jar` files or whatever contains the JSP API, which originates from a completely different servletcontainer make/version which in turn was actually not JSP 2.0 compliant. Get rid of those libraries. You don't need them. If you did this to workaround compilation errors, then you did it the wrong way. They should end up in compiletime classpath, not in the runtime classpath. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet / jakarta.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

#### See also:

- [How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/how-to-properly-configure-jakarta-ee-libraries-in-maven-pom-xml-for-tomcat/)

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, I am using Tomcat 10. I was getting this error using Apache NetBeans 12.3 IDE.

I added the following libraries:

1. [jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/2.0.0/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar)
2. [jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0 (1).jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/2.0.0/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar)

My code is running fine now.
[link to see where I added them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDkCe.png)

Comment: This solved my problem but tags such as `<c:forEach>` are not working.

Comment: solved my problem, but not working when updating database such as update, insert, delete, etc

Comment: <c:forEach> is working for me

Comment: Wow. Thank you, it helped me a lot! I was at my wits' end. But don't those dependencies duplicate each other? I only added the glassfish dependency (the second one), and it worked just as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Use the **WildFly server latest one**. This resolved my the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download all the required jar files from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/2.0.0). While adding the jar files, don't include the jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0.jar file, which is already included in the Tomcat10.0

This will work not only for the basic JSTL functions, but also for iterations using tags such as <c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

I too am having a similar problem. Except mine is for NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TryCatchFinally. I'm in the process of converting my web app to jakarta EE. I tried using the jars mentioned above and it didn't clear the error. After ripping the app to nothing, I found that the maven dependencies for SpringFramework 5.2.3 do not support Jakarta EE. I'll have to wait until Spring releases 6.0.0 of their framework. :-{