# javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator - running web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web, tomcat7

I tried to create easy web project at eclipse kepler on Lubuntu 13.10.

I met some trouble here.

When I running this project:

`Run as` => `Run on server`

It doesn't open registration form.

It looks as follows:

[image: registration]

for loading user form I need to add at the end of url `/addUser`.

it should load `AddUserServlet` and forward request to `adduser.jsp`.

here is my `weeb.xml`:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShowUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.lab.controler.servlets.ShowUsersServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShowUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/showUsers</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.lab.controler.servlets.AddUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addUser</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

content of `AddUserServlet`:

public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
UserService userService = new UserService();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/addUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    User user = new User();

    takeParameterFromRequest(request, user);

    boolean result = userService.addUser(user);

    getServletContext().setAttribute("boolean", result);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/UserAddingResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

private void takeParameterFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, User user) {
    user.setName(request.getParameter("firstname"));
    user.setLastname(request.getParameter("lastname"));
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    user.setGender(request.getParameter("optionsRadios"));
    user.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
}
```

snippet of `addUser.jsp`:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Registration Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">
        <b>Registration form</b>
    </h1>

<form method="post" action="addUser">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="20"
                    placeholder="first name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="20"
                   placeholder="last name" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is project hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

and loaded form looking:

[image: registration form]

I couldn't figure out why this happen... Any suggestions are appreciate.

**UPDATE:**

I followed **A Paul** suggestion, and added to **web.xml**:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>addUser</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This loaded register form, but after filling inputs and pressed **submit** it shows next:

[image: 500 http status]

Here is snippet from print stack trace:

```
INFO: Server startup in 964 ms
Feb 05, 2014 1:47:16 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 05, 2014 1:47:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure that this is your problem, but did you tried

`http://localhost:8080/UserRegistrationProject/addUser`

This should open the registration page

and if your want this form to open automatically on server run, then add the "addUser" value in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>addUser</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-taglibraryvalidator

Comment: I have read this one. This project completely follow this rules from accepted answer.

Comment: no I don't have this one. Content of `lib` folder is at project hierarchy slide.

Comment: Then just download this jar and place it inside your lib folder your error will be resolved.