# javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator error while executing a web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, jstl

Built a web project (using eclipse) in my local system and it is running as expected, however when I imported the same project to server machine am getting the "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator" error.

Things tried till now:

1) Added all jars in WEB-INF/lib directory.
2) Removed and added all jars in build path and class path.
3) Placed the "jstl-1.2" jar in both build path and WEB-INF/lib folders

Using JDK: 1.7

WebXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
version="3.0">
```

Full Stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1617)
>       org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:658)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:244)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:180)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>       com.controllers.Login.doPost(Login.java:58)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

Comment: check this link it may be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-taglibraryvalidator

Comment: Please check if your lib folder contains `servlet.jar` or not. It should not be there. Check if your server classpath to determine if there are any duplicate/missing jars or not. And also use findJar to determine jar of your class having NoClassDef error.

Comment: @Soorapadman: I set-up the project using the same link in my local system, however the error is shown when ran in another machine.

Comment: @Baddie: Earlier i tried moving javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar jars in WEB-INF/lib folder after reading the comments in similar posts I have removed those and just kept jstl-1.2 jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. All other jars including above two exists in Build path.