# JSTL tags are not working in eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am new to JSTL, I downloaded jstl-1.2.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl12jar.htm) to my web-content/web-inf/lib folder.
In my JSP file, I have mentioned:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

but everytime when I tries to use any JSTL tag, I got the error:

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

I am using eclipse photon, tomcat server-8.0.52.
What should I do? I have searched a lot on the internet about this, but I got the same errors. Please help me.

Comment: Did you rebuild project after you add lib?

Comment: yes, I rebuild my project. Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting error during runtime!
If you are using maven you must **add JSTL dependency**
or if you are not using maven or gradle you must **add the jar to the class path**.

Oh sorry!   TagLibraryValidator its your problem!
add jsp-api-2.2.jar to your lib folder.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjspapi22jar.htm

Comment: Author mentioned, that he has already added lib to web-content/web-inf/lib

Comment: Hi  Maxim Kasyanov, I think that Satnam123 must have some dependency same as  jsp-api-2.2.jar . Using maven may solve the problem i think!

Comment: I have TagLibraryValidator in javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator. But the problem is that it's definition is not found. As the error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Please provide any other solution.

Comment: may be this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-taglibraryvalidator

Comment: This solution didn't help me.

Comment: Can you share your project?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I got the solution. I just reinstall my java, eclipse, server and reconfigure jstl-1.2.jar. It start working well. I don't know how but this is only solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

ADD FOLLOWING DEPENDENCIES TO A WEB APPLICATION

To use this distribution with your own web applications, add the following JAR
files to the '/WEB-INF/lib' directory of your application:

- taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
- taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
- taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
- xalan-2.7.1.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar

If you do not use JSTL 1.0 tags then the "taglibs-standard-jstlel" JAR may be
omitted. If you do not use the XML library, then the Apache Xalan dependencies
may also be omitted.

**Sometimes only taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar library is enough. But if you want to use like forEach loop you should add two libraries to WEB-INF/lib of your project: Impl: taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar Spec: taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar**

https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/taglibs/taglibs-standard-1.2.5/README_bin.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To resolve it, I added jstl jars in *apache-tomcat/lib* and *web-content/web-inf/lib*.