I created a ToDO project using spring boot. In this everything is correct and all dependency are correct but it is still not running on browser?
This is my tree structure of files and directory

I expect that the output will be shown on browser when I put there the running port number.
It is giving error in the project directory structure but I think it seems correct.
I already cross check the files and tree structure of project.
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jul 28 09:06:19 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

I am getting this type of error.

Mention how you created the project. And post your entire POM as text, not image.

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021370/642706

Remove provided scope from your dependencies
