# java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Tags: java, jdbc

Its a part of Ajax jsp page

```
while(rs.next())  
  {
      System.out.println(rs.getString("Flat_No"));
      buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString("Flat_No")+"'>"+rs.getString("Flat_No")+"</option>";   
  }
```

There are total 4 values in Flat_No
it printing first values in console and aftr that i m getting error on my jsp page "java.sql.SQLException: No data found "

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a typical error when using the MS Access database through the poor JDBC-ODBC bridge driver and retrieving the same data more than once from the result set. You need to retrieve the data once and assign it to a variable and use the variable multiple times instead.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String flatNo = rs.getString("Flat_No");
    buffer += "<option value='" + flatNo + "'>" + flatNo + "</option>";   
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, doing this in a JSP file is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). See also [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc) for another concrete example how to do it the proper way.

Comment: Solved..Thanks..I am also in support for MVC..but my organisation says don't use it as my project business logic is not that big/my project mostly doing DB operations such as INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful with XSS and SQL injection attack holes.