# SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Tags: java, jdbc

i get an error wherein it says SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No data found, i cant seems to find the problem here. please help me, sorry for asking.

```
try{
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:ict11";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
       statement.executeUpdate( "DELETE from Employee where EmployeeID ="+txtId.getText()+"" );
       statement.close();
    con.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Successfully Deleted");
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
```

Comment: Does the data you are trying to remove exists?? But actually that too should not throw an exception..

Comment: you are using jdbc-odbc driver, not sure but check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498231/java-sql-sqlexception-no-data-found). Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I can think about 2 issues

1. This could be because of unnecessary white spaces that getText() doesn't eliminate. Try `txtId.getText().trim()`
2. URL might be wrong.

Apart from that, do the following to improve the code.

1. Print complete stack trace
2. Use PreparedStatement instead of statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
statement.executeUpdate( "DELETE from Employee where EmployeeID ="+txtId.getText()+"" );
```

try using this

```
statement.executeUpdate( "DELETE from Employee where EmployeeID ='"+txtId.getText()+"'" );
```

note the addition of single inverted comma at the start and end of `txtId.getText()`