# Login info of the user to JSP -- DAO and servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to put a simple login form to my application. Im still learning so I'm starting from the simplest.. The login is working perfectly, however I want to get some of the user info to my jsp using JSTL..

example in the username is ABC and password is abc123... I want to pass the data/info of ABC like his role and name to my jsp page.

LoginServlet.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package source;

/**
 *

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

try
{

     UserBean bean = new UserBean();
     bean.setUserName(request.getParameter("un"));
     bean.setPassword(request.getParameter("pw"));


     bean = UserDAO.login(bean);

     if (bean.isValid())
     {

          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
          session.setAttribute("users",bean);
          response.sendRedirect("dd1"); //logged-in page
     }

     else
          response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page
}


catch (Throwable theException)
{
     System.out.println(theException);
}
       }
    }
```

UserDAO

```
package source;

/**
 *

 */

   import java.sql.*;

   public class UserDAO
   {
      static Connection currentCon = null;
      static ResultSet rs = null;



      public static UserBean login(UserBean bean) {

         //preparing some objects for connection
         Statement stmt = null;

         String username = bean.getUsername();
         String password = bean.getPassword();

         String searchQuery = "select * from ifs_userrole where username='"+ username+ "' AND password = md5('"+ password +"')";



      try
      {
         //connect to DB
         currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
         stmt=currentCon.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
         boolean more = rs.next();

         // if user does not exist set the isValid variable to false
         if (!more)
         {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first");
            bean.setValid(false);
         }

         //if user exists set the isValid variable to true
         else if (more)
         {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String role = rs.getString("role");

            System.out.println("Welcome " + name+ role);
            bean.setName(name);
            bean.setRole(role);
            bean.setValid(true);
         }
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
      }

      //some exception handling
      finally
      {
         if (rs != null)    {
            try {
               rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
               rs = null;
            }

         if (stmt != null) {
            try {
               stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
               stmt = null;
            }

         if (currentCon != null) {
            try {
               currentCon.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            currentCon = null;
         }
      }

return bean;

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stored it as a session attribute with name `users`, so it should be available by `${users}`. The bean has two properties `name` and `role`, so it should be available as follows

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<p>User name: <c:out value="${users.name}" /></p>
<p>User role: <c:out value="${users.role}" /></p>
```

Since JSP 2.0 you *can* also just omit `<c:out>`:

```html
<p>User name: ${users.name}</p>
<p>User role: ${users.role}</p>
```

This will only open a potential XSS attack hole if you don't sanitize user-controlled data.

That said, I would change the attribute name from `users` to `user` since it's really only one user :) You've also a major design problem in your DAO class. The `Connection` and `ResultSet` should **absolutely not** be declared as static variables. It's not thread safe. Declare them in the very same method block as where you're executing the query. See also [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701) for another example.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks balusc... I've really learnes a lot from you also from others. You don't how much you've helped me with this. Thanks very much again

Answer (score 0):

your question is too generic, but maybe this work for your case...

you are adding the "user" bean into session context with this line `session.setAttribute("users",bean);` so, in your jsp you can do something like this;

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page import="com.your.package.hierarchy.UserBean" %>

<c:out value="sessionScope.users.username"/>
```

i don't remember if its "sessionContext", "sessionScope" or "session" the identifier for session scope attributes...

good luck!

Comment: The import statement is completely unnecessary.