# How to redirec to to HTML if exception occured

Tags: html, database, exception, servlets

I've been trying to search for a way to redirect to an HTML file if a SQLException occurs. I'm going to give you an example.

I have my connection class something like this:

```
public class DBConection{
    Connection con = null;
    public DBConnection() throws RuntimeException{      
        try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "12345";
            String db = "java";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + db, user, pass);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it from a Servlet class,

```
public class ElectionsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String RETURN_PAGE = "index.jsp";

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        DBConnection con = new DBConnection();
        response.sendRedirect(RETURN_PAGE);
    }
}
```

If an error ocurres during the DBConnection I want to redirect it to my RETURN_PAGE. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add try-catch block to your `doPost` method and if any exception occurs in try block, catch that exception and redirect to `RETURN_PAGE`.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try{
        DBConnection con = new DBConnection();
        }catch(Exception e){
        response.sendRedirect(RETURN_PAGE);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the builtin container managed exception handling facilities. You need to rethrow the caught exception as `ServletException` and define the error page as `<error-page>` in `web.xml`.

You only need to change your DB access logic accordingly. It's far from sane, safe and efficient. The exception handling is also strange. You seem to have ripped this from a completely outdated resource given the fact that you're using the deprecated MySQL JDBC driver class name.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```java
public final class Database {
    
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/java";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "12345";

    static {      
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("The JDBC driver is missing in classpath!", e);
        }
    }

    private Database() {
        // Don't allow construction.
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }

}
```

Finally use and handle it in the servlet as follows:

```java
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Connection connection = null;
    // ...

    try{
        connection = Database.getConnection();
        // ...
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ServletException("DB fail!", e);
    }
    finally {
        // ...
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

*(better would be to wrap the DB job in a DAO class which in turn throws a `SQLException`, but that's a different problem)*

And declare the error page in `web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/database.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

You can of course also use `<location>/index.jsp</location>` but that's not very friendly to the enduser as it's completely confusing why he returns back to there. Rather put that as a link in the `database.jsp` error page along with something user friendly like

> *Sorry, an unrecoverable problem has occurred while communicating with the DB. Please click the following link to return to the index page.*

#### See also:

- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701)

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered, but I'll add a few comments:

- I don't see the need of catching `SQLException` and `ClassNotFoundException` only to rethow `RuntimeException` instances. If you're planning to do nothing when this exception raises in your `DBConnection` class, just add `throws` to your constructor signature. With that, the compiler will check that a try-catch block be added when using your constructor.
- There's no need of adding `throws RuntimeException` to your constructor signature. `RuntimeException` is a non-checked exception.