# No data records returned from Oracle 10g DB using JSP

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc, oracle10g

I have inserted the following java code in the body part of my jsp page to retrieve the records of the table FLIGHTDATA from a Oracle 10g database. But after the execution of the Class.forName(...) line the program directly goes to finally block and closing the connection without returning any data. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ? Thanks - Somnath

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<%
out.println("<table border='1'><tr>");
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs_1hop = null;
ResultSetMetaData rsm_1hop = null;
try {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "system", "system");
statement = connection.createStatement();
// sql query to retrieve values from the secified table.
String QueryString = "SELECT * from FLIGHTDATA";
rs_1hop = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
rsm_1hop = rs_1hop.getMetaData();
int colCnt = rsm_1hop.getColumnCount();

for (int i=1; i<=colCnt; ++i) {
    out.println("<th>" + rsm_1hop.getColumnName(i) + "</th>");
}
out.println("</tr>");

while (rs_1hop.next()) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    for (int i=1; i<=colCnt; ++i)
        out.println("<td>" + rs_1hop.getString(i) + "</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
    if (statement != null)
        statement.close();
    if (connection != null)
        connection.close();
}
out.println("</table><br><br>");
%>
```

After adding the ServletException in the catch block as commented by BalusC, and adding the odbc6.jar files under /WEB-INF/lib, I am getting the following error message which I suppose is due to the jdbc driver not found.

I also tried adding the jar files under Apache Tomcat installation dir /ROOT/web-apps/WEB_INF/lib so that they are available for all web-apps but the problem persists.

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: DB interaction failed!           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: DB interaction failed!
     org.apache.jsp.retrievePossibleRoutes_jsp._jspService(retrievePossibleRoutes_jsp.java:96)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.retrievePossibleRoutes_jsp._jspService(retrievePossibleRoutes_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But after the execution of the Class.forName(...) line the program directly goes to finally block*

That can only happen if a `ClassNotFoundException` was been thrown. This means that concrete class as specified by the given class name is not in the webapp's runtime classpath at all. That class is part of the Oracle JDBC driver. Putting the Oracle JDBC driver JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp should fix that problem.

Further I strongly recommend you to do *something* in that empty `catch (Exception e) {}` block to indicate that an exception has occurred. Right now you're stabbing clueless around in the dark as to what really happened. If you have rethrown it as a `ServletException`, then you'd have gotten a much more self-explaining error page instead of a halfbaked JSP result.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);    
}
```

Last but not least, writing Java code in a JSP file is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). How to salvage this properly, check this answer: [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701).

---

**Update** as per your update:

> *After adding the ServletException in the catch block as commented by BalusC, and adding the odbc6.jar files under /WEB-INF/lib, I am getting the following error message which I suppose is due to the jdbc driver not found.*

Then it's the wrong JAR file (i.e. it's not the one containing the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` class), or you didn't rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp properly. Make sure that you've downloaded the right JDBC driver for your Oracle database version as listed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). Make sure that you've properly rebuilt/redeployed/restarted the webapp.

---

> *I also tried adding the jar files under Apache Tomcat installation dir /ROOT/web-apps/WEB_INF/lib so that they are available for all web-apps but the problem persists.*

This is nonsense. Undo this change. To make a JAR available to all deployed webapps, put it in Tomcat's own `/lib` folder (the one straight in Tomcat installation folder). But that won't solve your problem if it's the wrong JAR file.

Comment: Hi, I have already added the ojdbc6.jar under the Libraries tab of my project build path. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: No. You'd need to configure it in the *Deployment Assembly* section of project's properties as well to get the JAR file to ultimately end up in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the built WAR. But that's plain clumsy. Just manually drop the physical JAR file in project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Don't forget to undo the changes you made before there in the build path. Those changes are unnecessary and may conflict the one and other. The IDE will already take care the proper build path settings automatically when you just drop the JAR file in project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: yes, I removed the files from the project build path --> Libraries and added them under <App-root-context>/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib as well as under <Apache Tomcat installation dir>/web-apps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib to be available for all web-apps. But the problem persists with now a detailed error message thrown due to the ServletException added in catch block.

Comment: The Oracle JDBC driver download page tells that you need `ojdbc14.jar` file for a 10g. Check the link in my answer update. You've mentioned that you've a `ojdbc6.jar` and `odbc6.jar` which are thus wrong for a 10g.

Comment: Yes I downloaded the right file and it worked. The jar file was wrong. But I would like to add that despite adding the jar to the /WEB-INF/lib, I also had to add the path of classes12.jar and ojdbc14.jar to the system path to get rid of the ClassNotFoundException that I was getting. Your comments were very helpful. Thanks a lot.