# How to handle multiple users access a web page at the same time without socket close in any users side

Tags: jsp, database-connection, database-server

I have a problem where I have tried to login two or more web browser/same browsers with difference tab to the same web page, there will had an error said

> Io exception: Socket closed

in either one side when refresh/login in the same time.

Should I use multithread open connection? If yes how it be done?
Can anyone help with this problem?
The program is written in JSP.

Comment: Where is the code ? Provide full error stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are not declaring and storing the SQL `Connection` as a static or instance variable *anywhere* in your code.

E.g, this is *bad*:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Connection connection;
    // Or
    private static Connection connection;

}
```

It should be declared, created and closed within the *very same* method block as where you're executing the SQL query.

So, this is *good*:

```
public class SomeDAO {

    public SomeEntity find(Long id) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        // ...

        try {
            connection = database.getConnection();
            // ...
        }
        finally {
            // ...
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch(SQLException ignore) {}
        }

        return someEntity;
    }
```

#### See also:

- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701)