# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: uges.servlets.MyQuery: method <init>()V not found

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jess

I'm using Tomcat v 7, and Jess v 7.0

This is the exception I'm getting

```
root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: uges.servlets.MyQuery:       method <init>()V not found
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.jav  a:911)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
org.apache.jsp.catalog_jsp._jspService(catalog_jsp.java:121)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: uges.servlets.MyQuery: method <init>()V not found
org.apache.jsp.catalog_jsp._jspService(catalog_jsp.java:69)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

and this is my source code of class MyQuery
    package uges.servlets;

```
import jess.*;;

public class MyQuery
{

private static QueryResult result;
public MyQuery(Rete engine) throws JessException
{
    getQuery(engine);
}
public QueryResult getQuery(Rete engine) throws JessException
{
    result = engine.runQueryStar("all-products", new ValueVector());
    return result;
}
public String getString(String str) throws JessException
{
    String srtResult;
    srtResult = result.getString(str);
    return srtResult;

}
public Float getFloat(String str) throws JessException
{
    float flt;
    flt = result.getFloat(str);
    return flt;

}
public boolean next() throws JessException
{
    boolean next;
    next = result.next();
    return next;

}
}
```

and this is the Catalog Servlet
    package uges.servlets;

```
import jess.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Catalog extends BaseServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    checkInitialized();

    try {
        String customerId =
            (String) request.getParameter("customerId");
        if (customerId == null || customerId.length() == 0) {
            dispatch(request, response, "/index.html");
            return;
        }

        request.getSession().invalidate();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        session.setAttribute("customerId", customerId);
        session.setAttribute("orderNumber",
                             String.valueOf(getNewOrderNumber()));

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        Rete engine = (Rete) servletContext.getAttribute("engine");

        //engine.reset();
          MyQuery result = new MyQuery(engine);
          //engine.runQueryStar("all-products", new ValueVector());
            request.setAttribute("queryResult",result);               

    } catch (JessException je) {
        throw new ServletException(je);
    }

    dispatch(request, response, "/catalog.jsp");
}

private int getNewOrderNumber() throws JessException {
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    Rete engine = (Rete) servletContext.getAttribute("engine");
    int nextOrderNumber = 
        engine.executeCommand("(get-new-order-number)").intValue(null);
    return nextOrderNumber;
}

public void destroy() {
    try {
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        Rete engine = (Rete) servletContext.getAttribute("engine");
        String factsFileName =
            servletContext.getInitParameter("factsfile");
        File factsFile = new File(factsFileName);
        File tmpFile =
            File.createTempFile("facts", "tmp", factsFile.getParentFile());
        engine.executeCommand("(save-facts " + tmpFile.getAbsolutePath() +
                              " order recommend line-item next-order-number)");
        factsFile.delete();
        tmpFile.renameTo(factsFile);

    } catch (Exception je) {
        // Log error
    } 
}


}
```

the JSP catalog.jsp

```
<HTML>
<%@ page import="jess.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id="queryResult" class="uges.servlets.MyQuery" scope="request"/>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Ordering from Tekmart.com</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Tekmart.com Catalog</H1>
Select the items you wish to purchase and press "Check Order" to continue.
<FORM action="/Order/recommend" method="POST">
<TABLE border="1">
<TR><TH>Name</TH>
    <TH>Catalog #</TH>
    <TH>Price</TH>
    <TH>Purchase?</TH>
</TR>
<% while (queryResult.next()) {
    String partNum =
            queryResult.getString("part-number");%> 
   <TR>
     <TD><%= queryResult.getString("name") %></TD>
     <TD><%= queryResult.getString("part-number") %></TD>
     <TD><%= queryResult.getFloat("price") %></TD>
     <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="items"
                value=<%= '"' + partNum + '"'%>></TD>
   </TR> 
 <% } %>                 
</TABLE>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Check Order">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any clue will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The JSP engine is trying to instantiate your class via reflection using a no-arg constructor.  You have not defined a no-arg constructor, so this error occurs.  A bean must have a no-arg constructor.  If you need to set properties on the bean, use `jsp:set-property`.

If you absolutely cannot add a no-arg constructor, then you must instantiate it outside of a `jsp:use-bean` tag and add it to the proper context yourself, as in

```
< %   
  pkg.Foo foo = new pcg.Foo(constructor-arg);  
  context.setAttribute("foo", foo);  
% >
```

This violates the basic JavaBean requirement for a no-arg constructor.

I believe once it's been created in the proper scope, other JSPs can refer to it with `jsp:use-bean`.

Comment: thanks :) but what if I can't add a no-arg constructor .. how can I set properties? could you please give me an example! another thing I've googled a lot and found that such error is because something wrong with jars' versions! any clue?!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but why some beans need to implement Serialize interface?

Answer (score 0):

You've in the preprocessing servlet **already** set the `queryResult` in the request scope.

```
request.setAttribute("queryResult",result);
```

So you do **not** need to use `<jsp:useBean>` at all. Remove the following line altogether:

```
<jsp:useBean id="queryResult" class="uges.servlets.MyQuery" scope="request"/>
```

Because your servlet has set it as a request attribute, the object is **already** in EL available by `${queryResult}`. But due to the strange design of the class itself, it's hard to properly access it in EL, so you'll ineed need to resort to old school *scriptlets*. You only need to obtain it first by `request.getAttribute("queryResult")`.

For a better design approach, check the [servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701).