# Accessing SpringMVC model key value inside java code

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

```
@RequestMapping(value = "",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", doctorDetails);
    return "doctorchannelling/index";
}
```

I have added this controller in my SpringMVC project now I need to access the element doctorDetails in a java code which is inside a jsp

how can I call this `doctorDetails` inside `<% %>` Mark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like below

```
<% String message = (String)request.getAttribute("message"); %>
```

or

```
<%
    String message = ${message};
%>
```

Comment: `${message}` will print the `request` attribute directly, so why is that assigned to `String` again

Comment: @sanDecruz it is just for the reference to OP, if OP wants to make use of this somewhere in the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the EL to print them as,

```
${message}
```

If it is a `String` set in the request. For `Model` objects use ,

```
${message.fieldName}
```

**See Also**

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [printing servlet request attributes with expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029507/printing-servlet-request-attributes-with-expression-language)

Comment: I'm getting error saying cannot resolve symbol "message". 
that variable message is defined inside the controller. 
in usual cases when I deal with jsp & servlets i have used the code segments which you mentioned but here I’m not able to retrieve the value

Comment: what is `doctorDetails` and are you redirecting it to the page you have the EL code ?

Comment: @DownVoter Can you pls leave a comment ?

Comment: @sanDecruz can you pls remove my downvote also, it is an accepted answer

Comment: doctorDetails contains String value.. No I didn't
I have used the below code & now i'm getting the aswer
<% String message = (String)request.getAttribute("message"); %>
Thanks a lot