# Error occure while using two resultset in same table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am a beginner. In my project I am using Java and Mysql. While doing a code I got an error. That code is mentioning below

```
<%
       ResultSet rs=s.fetchtask(userid);
       while(rs.next())
       {
%> 
         <table border="1">
             <tr><td>
              <% int qnid=(rs.getInt("question_id")); 
                 ResultSet rs1=s.fetchqn(qnid);
                 String qn=rs1.getString("question");
              %> 
                  <% out.println(qn);%>
               </td></tr>
         </table>
      <%
          }
       %>
```

But when I am not using the second fetch its working

```
<%
       ResultSet rs=s.fetchtask(userid);
       while(rs.next())
       {
%> 
         <table border="1">
             <tr><td>
              <% int qnid=(rs.getInt("question_id"));     
              %> 
                  <% out.println(qnid);%>
               </td></tr>
         </table>
      <%
          }
       %>
```

When I am using this code there is no problem. Please somebody help me. The error showing is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /setter.jsp at line 142

 139:                        // ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM temp_qb  WHERE question_id="+qnid+"");
 140:                         ResultSet rs1=s.fetchqn(qnid);
 141:                           //  ResultSet rs1=s.fetchqn(qnid);
 142:                         String qn=rs1.getString("question");
 143:                          %> 
 144:                          <% //out.println(qn);
 145:                          %>
```

Comment: Please don't use scriplets. And post your error.

Comment: What is `s` with the method `fetchqn(int)`? I'd bet that's where the problem lies.

Comment: its the object created for the java page where the data base queries are written

Comment: Please ignore JSP for now. JSP has got completely nothing to do with your concrete problem and is only making things to look complicated and confusing. Put that Java/JDBC code in a normal Java class with a method which returns `List<Question>`. Test that normal Java class using another normal Java class with a `main()` method. Once you get the desired functionality to work, just import and call the very same normal Java class in a servlet (or scriptlet if you want to practice a practice which is discouraged more than a decade ago). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5003142/

Comment: @Salini  can you please show  where you created the object for `s`  ?

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="s" class="db.Query"/> this code is given at the top(inside body tag)of the same page.

Comment: @BalusC Can you please show an Example

Comment: The link in my previous comment was not posted for decoration. Click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. The problem was only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists. SO by using another statement it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

- You are not checking the result set to make sure you have the data. That could lead to exceptions.

With so little to go on, I suggest you try this and see if you still get the same error.

```
<%
       ResultSet rs=s.fetchtask(userid);
       while(rs.next())
       {
%> 
         <table border="1">
             <tr><td>
              <% int qnid=(rs.getInt("question_id")); 
                 ResultSet rs1=s.fetchqn(qnid);
                 while(rs1.next())
                 { 
                    String qn=rs1.getString("question");
                    out.println(qn);
                 } 
              %>
               </td></tr>
         </table>
<%
       }
%>
```

- Also make sure you are using the correct column name to fetch the data from the result set.
- Take care to close the result set and db connections properly once you are done using them.

Finally,

- Please avoid using scriplets if you are building something new.

Comment: It is also getting error in the first while loop, means on the line while(rs.next())

Comment: @Salini it will be great if you **edit your question** and post the stacktrace of the exception thrown in your `ResultSet rs=s.fetchtask(userid);`