# How to retrieve data from a database from a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a .jsp file which basically displays data from a database. The database class is defined separately in a .java file. To get the contents of the database I am calling the getData method of the database. But the function calls made never execute and nothing is returned.

However if I return any pre-computed values from the getData function, then it executes fine.

I want to know how can I access the database from the .jsp file.

I don't want to add the java code directly to the .jsp file. So I want to do it via a method call.

---

Function from .jsp file:

```
<%
    ArrayList<String> al = com.Database.getData();
%>
```

---

Java function:

```
getData(){
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs   = null;
    al.add("first");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT rs FROM DATABASE";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            String str  = rs.getString("str");
            al.add(str);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    al.add("nikunj ");
    al.add("banka ");
    return al;
}
```

---

The contents of the arraylist after the call are {"first", "nikunj", "banka"} and no data from the database.

How can I get the data from the database. I have tried creating a static block that will populate the ArrayList at the start of the program but even this is not working.

Comment: You're selecting the field `rs` from the table `DATABASE`, and then trying to get the field `str` out of the ResultSet...

Comment: `SELECT rs` and then `getString("str")`? You're not selecting the field you're trying to get at.

Comment: rs will hold all the data in the database. and I will get the data sequentially and add it to the al.

Comment: Aren't you getting any error traces?

Comment: No error traces are printed. Just the 3 strings get added to the al.

Comment: Are you sure you have records on your table?

Comment: Should you not be using rs.getString("rs"); ?

Comment: Check logs, you should use the same name /columnname returns in resultset . Most important close the resources ( connections , statements,resultsets)

Comment: Use Select * From Table and rs.getString("columnName") for each column

Comment: Yes I think I have the problem sorted out now. From the error logs I can see that the class not found exception is getting thrown. (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can also use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) if you want to avoid Java code in your JSP. e.g.:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
                   user="root"  password="pass123"/>

<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL SQL</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:query var = "result" dataSource="${dataSource}">
SELECT str FROM table
</sql:query>

<table border=1>
<c:forEach var="row" query="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.str}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Maybe you want to read:

- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [JSP using MVC and JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc/5003701#5003701)
- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)

Comment: @Nikunj Banka: Paul Vargas is correct, you should avoid Java code in `JSPs`. A `servlet` would be the best thing to use here. Use the appropriate `GET` or `POST` method of the `servlet`, retrieve the data from the database, then write it in the `servlet` to the `request` object to display it in the `JSP` using `JSTL` tags.

Comment: It is another way to do it too. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

create a jsp have this code:

```
<%
  List list = main.myPack.Test.getData();
  System.out.println(list);

%>
```

create a static method of a class like this :

```
public static List getData()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

            System.out.println("invoked");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("making connection");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "welcome");
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");
            System.out.println("fetching data");
            while(rset.next())
            {
                String name = rset.getString("student_name");
                String id = rset.getString("student_id");
                list.add(name);
                list.add(id);
                System.out.println(name+" "+id);
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
```

then call the jsp thats it what you want
        }

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL query column with ResultSet.getString() methods dear. If you used SELECT str FROM database_table it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Harsha has pointed you in the right direction. `ResultSet.getString()` has two overloads.

- One takes an `Int` that represent which column, ordinally, you want to retrieve.
- The other, which you used, take a `String` which would be the column name in the result set.

Since your SELECT statement only selected the column "rs" you have no column "str" in your result set to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should check your sql statement you have database error i think!

```
//String sql = "SELECT rs FROM DATABASE";
String sql = "SELECT str FROM DATABASE";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
   String str  = rs.getString("str"); //you get "str" field here not "rs"
   al.add(str);
}
```