# How to include a JSP page into a custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, tld, custom-tags

I am creating a custom tag directive where I have to print a table of data from database.

So far I have created:

**JSP page:**

```jsp
 <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/fact.tld" prefix="veritis"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <h1><veritis:print name="emp" /></h1> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**TLD file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
 <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
 <short-name>factorial</short-name>
  <tag>
      <name>print</name>
      <tag-class>com.veritis.jsp.FactTag</tag-class>
      <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>name</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

and a `Class` file for which fetches data from database using other `Class` file. This class file also extends `TagSupport` to overwrite needed TLD methods.

```java
public class FactTag extends TagSupport{
    String value="emp";
    public String getValue() {
        return value;    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int doStartTag(){
        return Tag.SKIP_BODY;
    }
    public int doEndTag() throws JspTagException{

        String emp1=getValue();
            
       try{
           //The following line is to get the JSP Writer Object
           //similar to PrintWriter in Servlet
           JspWriter out=pageContext.getOut();
           
           TableData tbd=new TableData();
           List<Employee> listOfEmp=tbd.getAllEMployees();
           for(Employee emp:listOfEmp)
           {
               System.out.println(emp);
           }
       }catch(Exception e){}
       return Tag.SKIP_PAGE;
    }
   
}
```

Now I have data in my `List<emp>` and I want to print that in JSP file. I could print that by using out object but my requirement is not to use out object rather print by including other JSP file or any other way.

**Note:** Though I am taking `input(emp)` from JSP, I am not using it for now. Rather I am generating a static query to fetch the data.

Comment: What other JSP file? There's a lot of ways to do it, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Like sending this List of employees object to one jsp file to print it and including that. To be clear I do not want to write Java code print table instead I want to print it using JSTL

Comment: A custom tag is the wrong tool for the job you had in mind. RomanC gave a shot in the right direction which is already chewed out for years long. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5003142 A MVC framework will reduce boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSTL `c:forEach` tag to iterate through the list of `Employee`. If you don't want to use frameworks based on servlets like Struts2 or Spring MVC, you can use raw servlet

```
@WebServlet("/employees")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        TableData tbd=new TableData();
        List<Employee> listOfEmp=tbd.getAllEMployees();        
        request.setAttribute("listOfEmp", listOfEmp);

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/emloyee.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

#### employee.jsp:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<%-- Using JSTL c:forEach and c:out to loop a list and display items in a table --%>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.listOfEmp}" var="emp">
<tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use JSP fragment page containing a table and include it to the main page.

#### employee.jsp:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="employee_table.jsp"/>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

#### employee_table.jsp:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%-- Using JSTL c:forEach and c:out to loop a list and display items in a table --%>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.listOfEmp}" var="emp">
<tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman C. Though this is not my requirement, I could do this way. My assignment is to implement it in custom tag. I have finally used pageContext().setAttribute().forward(request,response) to forward that user list object and printed in the forwaded jsp using JSTL.