# Access an object in JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have this problem.

Is there any problem on directly accessing POJO class or an entity class in JSP, what is the best practice for that ?

Comment: Using [jstl tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) ?

Comment: What kind of problem do you expect? Please describe in more detail.

Comment: i want to know whether its a good practice to creating objects of our class in JSP pages.

Comment: If you are using Spring MVC then you put the data in model object and as mentioned by fvu, access the model using JSTL tags, that is the best practise. Google it, you will get many examples

Comment: yes using jstl tags

Comment: @jithin, yes JSTL and Spring form tags is the right way to use it.

Comment: @Chaitanya while using jstl to display an object in jsp do we need to specify the class name or something in the JSP page ?

Comment: @jithin, No not required to specify the class in JSP. Follow the answer given by Pascal, you will understand.

Comment: thanks all for the help

Answer (score 2):

Please see [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s excellent answer on the subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/2112089

Basically, accessing POJOs is discouraged because it leads to unmaintainable code. It is much better to use JSTL and Expression Language (EL).

To do that, here's his example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.name}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The rest of @BalusC's series on JSP:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097732/2112089

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106909/2112089

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003701/2112089

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542297/2112089