get javascript table element in jsp
I'm using a jsp and I need to do something like this but it doesn't work, the elements of table doesn't show in my page and I tried to replace the extension of my jsp file into html and it works correctly so I think that I have some problem with jsp and js but I really need my file to be a jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tableau de données</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="data-table" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>

    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

    <tbody>
      <%-- Insertion des lignes de tableau à partir de JavaScript --%>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => `your text`{
      const array = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3', 'Element 4', 'Element 5'];
      const tableBody = document.querySelector('#data-table tbody');

      if (tableBody) {
        array.forEach((element, index) => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${index + 1}</td>
            <td>${element}</td>
          `;
          tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Impossible de trouver le corps de la table.');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>




what I got in my browser with the jsp file is



Index
Value




1



1



1



1



1




but when I try to put this code in an html file I get



Index
Value




1
Element 1


2
Element 2


3
Element 3


4
Element 4


5
Element 5



I tried to replace the extenxion of my jsp file into html and it works correctly but I think that I have some problem zith jsp and js but I really need my file to be a jsp

Can you share working URL with some mocked data?

${...} is also executed in JSP (it's called "Expression Language", "EL", look up it). So either escape it as per the abovelinked duplicate in order to keep it for generated JS code or, better, put JS code in its own JS file and include via script src. A pure JSP solution without the need for all that JavaScript can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/q/5003142
