# How do I call a specific Java method on a click/submit event of a specific button in JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

My Java file is:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void method1() {    
        // some code
    }

    public void method2() {
        //some code
    }

    public void method3() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

In my JSP page I have three HTML buttons.

If I click on `button1`, then only `method1` will be called, if I click on `button2` then only `method2` will execute, and if `button3`, then only `method3`, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You submit you request to a Servlet  and conditionally call the required  function from the servlet.

Comment: You cannot do it directly, as JavaScript is ran at client-side and JSP at server-side, so you need to submit your request to the servlet and the servlet will do processing and returns the result. You may use AJAX to do it asynchronously

Comment: Is it training task? Do you plan to use web frameworks?

Comment: Can you do this testing just from an internet page on a home computer without the hassle of having to use a server. Could I have a page made on my desktop and then just use that to call a method in a class that will call a java method?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just give the individual button elements a unique name. When pressed, the button's name is available as a request parameter the usual way like as with input elements.

You only need to make sure that the button inputs have `type="submit"` as in `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit">` and **not** `type="button"`, which only renders a "dead" button purely for `onclick` stuff and all.

E.g.

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="submit" name="button3" value="Button 3" />
</form>
```

with

```
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {
            myClass.method1();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {
            myClass.method2();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button3") != null) {
            myClass.method3();
        } else {
            // ???
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some-result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, use `<button type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit">`, then you can give them all the same name, but an unique value. The value of the `<button>` won't be used as label, you can just specify that yourself as child.

E.g.

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="button3">Button 3</button>
</form>
```

with

```
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        String button = request.getParameter("button");

        if ("button1".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method1();
        } else if ("button2".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method2();
        } else if ("button3".equals(button)) {
            myClass.method3();
        } else {
            // ???
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some-result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/how-to-call-servlet-from-html-form-in-jsp-file-without-getting-http-status-404)
- [How do I pass current item to Java method by clicking a hyperlink or button in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078701/how-do-i-pass-current-item-to-java-method-by-clicking-a-hyperlink-or-button-in-j)

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="post" action="servletName">   
     <input type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1"/>
     <input type="submit" id="btn2" name="btn2"/>
</form>
```

on pressing it request will go to servlet on the servlet page check which button is pressed and then accordingly call the needed method as objectName.method

Comment: I have used Java a lot in the past six months, so I am fairly familar with the code. I however have not had to develop any pages that use the java class to call a button. Can I just create class with public methods and then have my web page call each method individual with JQuery or some other intermediate language?

Comment: @DougHauf you can use servlet for this. Servlet post and get method can be used by javascript. This post will give you rough idea on how it works http://www.doublecloud.org/2012/12/developing-web-application-with-jquery-and-java-servlet/

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding action="#{yourBean.function1}" on each button (changing of course the method function2, function3, or whatever you need).
If that does not work, you can try the same with the onclick event.

Anyway, it would be easier to help you if you tell us what kind of buttons are you trying to use, a4j:commandButton or whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have web.xml then

**HTML/JSP**

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <display-name>Servlet Name</display-name>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>package.SomeController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Java**
SomeController.java

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Write your code below");
}
```