# how to invoke a function on dataTable rowOnClick event

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a data table in my JSP page and i want to invoke a java function when we clicking a ROW.

```
JSP CODE : 

    <t:dataTable id="searchcorrectionDetailTable" rows="10"
                        value="#{correctionDataBean.detailList}"
                        var="DetailResultList1" styleClass="dataTable" cellspacing="0"
                        width="100%" border="0"
                        rowOnMouseOver="this.origClassName = this.className;this.className='row_mouse row_link';"
                        rowOnMouseOut="if (this.origClassName) this.className = this.origClassName;"
                        headerClass="tableHead" rowClasses="rowone,row_alt"
                        **rowOnClick="???"**>

                        <t:column>
                            <h:commandLink id="MEMINFCL282111099"
                                action="#{searchControllerBean.getDisplayEditData}">                            
                                <h:outputText id="year" value="#{DetailResultList1.year}" styleClass="generalText" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </t:column>
    </t:dataTable>
```

I want to invoke this java class function searchControllerBean.getDisplayEditData on rowOnClick EVENT...

How should i call this function on rowOnClick="???"

Pls guide me to get this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723812/how-do-i-call-a-java-method-on-button-click-event-of-jsp-or-html. This will help I guess. They are indeed achieving the same functionality(invoking java function on click of button).

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using the combination of jsp and jsf2.2?