# Why does Servlet think my empty HTML file element has a file in it?

Tags: servlets, file-upload, is-empty

I am using a Java Servlet to handle an html form and it includes a file input element:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="file" multiple />
```

I used the example code in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1) to process multiple files at once. The code I'm using is:

```
List<Part> fileParts = req.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file" multiple="true">
for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
            String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
            // Do stuff here
}
```

This code works great. My problem is, when I don't attach anything, my code still thinks fileParts has a Part object in it. Doing some debugging, the Part object does seem to be there, but of course there is no InputStream or SubmittedFileName to get, since I didn't upload any files. Why is this? I am new to lambda functions and collections, but it seems like this "fileParts" Collection should be empty when I don't select any files for upload.

Comment: Check your browser network console. Does it submit the input empty? That's still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how HTML works.

The same is true for non-file inputs. When an empty input is submitted, you get an empty value, not `null`. The difference is significant. A value of `null` represents absence of the input field. This is particularly useful when the form has multiple submit buttons and you'd like to [distinguish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723812/how-do-i-call-a-specific-java-method-on-click-submit-event-of-specific-button-in) the button pressed.

Given a `<input type="text" name="foo">`,

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");

if (foo == null) {
    // foo was not submitted at all.
} else if (foo.isEmpty()) {
    // foo is submitted without value.
} else {
    // foo is submitted with a value.
}
```

And a `<input type="file" name="bar">`,

```
Part bar = request.getPart("bar");

if (bar == null) {
    // bar was not submitted at all.
} else if (bar.getSize() == 0) {
    // bar is submitted without value.
} else {
    // bar is submitted with a value.
}
```