# Java - What is pageContext, request, contextPath

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to Java development and I have been thrown into the deep end and have been told to create a http server. I am currently trying to set up a button to shutdown the server after clicking it. I found a solution here:

> [How do I call a specific Java method on click/submit event of specific button in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723812/how-do-i-call-a-specific-java-method-on-click-submit-event-of-specific-button-in?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My question now is what does the accepted answer mean by `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet`?

**EDIT 1:**

I am using the built in http server. THe tutorial I followed to set it up is:

> https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1040097/Create-a-Simple-Web-Server-in-Java-HTTP-Server

Comment: Try searching [Jsp Implicit Objects](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-implicit-objects/) and you'll find all your answers

Comment: The built-in HTTP server is unable to handle JSP. If you want to use JSP/servlet technology you should use a servlet server like Jetty or Tomcat.