# Mapping a HTML button to call a method in a controller class in Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I am having some difficulties in calling a method when a button is clicked.

In my Index.JSP

I have the following section of HTML code

```
 <div class="hero-copy">
                    <h1 class="hero-title mt-0">Deep Algorithm by Sadman Sakib</h1>
                    <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
                    <div class="hero-cta">
                        <a class="button button-primary" onclick="">View Projects</a>
                        <div class="lights-toggle">
                            <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked"  >
                            <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now "View Projects" is a button which will print "Hello" out in the console, I am not sure what I should be using to call the method in my controller. At the moment I am using onClick but am not sure what I should put as a parameter.

This is my controller class

```
    @Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/projects")
    public void add()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

This is my view, user will click view projects and it will print hello out in the console, how would I go about doing this?

[image]

**EDIT**

When I use  a form it works, however when using href it does not link to my controller.

```
<form action="add">
                    <input type="submit"  class="button button-primary" value="Me">
                </form>

             
                <span>View GitHub</span>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}add"><h3>View GitHub</h3></a>
```

How can I use href to link back to my controller. Do I need to import some dependencies/taglines

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723812/how-do-i-call-a-specific-java-method-on-a-click-submit-event-of-a-specific-butto

Comment: Definitely not the same.

Comment: Okay. You can just use <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello">Click</a>

Comment: Does not work, I have tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I managed to fix it, I should call my controller using href like this

```
href="<c:url value="/projects"/>
```

Cheers to everyone who helped

Answer (score 0):

First you must understand what the controller is doing. The controller is mapping the request which have the path `/projects`, so usually, the url will be something like http://localhost:8080/projects if your app is running on port 8080. Upon calling '/projects' from your browser, the method `add()` will be executed.

The easiest way to trigger the method `add()` in the controller is using `href` in the link.

The code will be as follows:

```
<a class="button button-primary" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/projects">View Projects</a>
```

If you really want to use the onclick method, then you must create a javascript function and call the url which is mapping to `/projects`

*Update 28/06/20*

The code will not work because the method being invoked is returning void. Add @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) on the method then it should work just fine.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/projects")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void add()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this does not work, I am trying to get to the next page.

Comment: Normally a controller does not return void, that was why the code was not working. I have updated the answer so it works as expected. I have tested it and it works

Comment: Still does not work, I have tried this method. It worked for my last html page

Comment: If i create a form like this

<form action ="name of controller"> it works but this is not what I want to do.

Comment: I have  made an edit to the post, clarifying some stuff