# Get user selected item from dynamic list in jsp page and pass to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

This is part of a research project. I have a list that is iterated in the jsp page. I'm not able to get the value of the item in the list the user selects as it picks the first in the list when I retrieve it in the servlet. Any pointers or solution would be helpful.

I tried using `[status.index]` to the name tag but there too I have no idea which index the user picked to get in the servlet.

```
<c:forEach items="${TSName}" var="TSName" varStatus="status">
<b>Resource Name:</b> ${TSName}<br>
<b>Summary:</b> ${Summary[status.index]}<br>
<b>URL: ${URL[status.index]}</b><br>
<b>Average Rating:</b> ${AvgRating[status.index]}<br>
<input type="hidden" value="${TSName}" name="tool" />
<input type="hidden" value=" ${URL[status.index]}" name="url" />
<input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="${requestScope.uuid}" />
<input type="submit" value="Proceed" /><br><br>
</c:forEach>
```

I would only want the exact item the user picks from the list instead of the first item of each. I'm sorry if I made it too confusing. If anything is unclear I can clarify.

@BalusC I'm sorry but you didn't answer anywhere close to my question. I had mentioned it a part of a research project and you just presumed the list of items were generated was based on a id. There were multiple conditions to get that list of items for the users. @Paul provided the most simplest and accurate answer to my question so if you could reopen the question I could mark his answer as the solution.

Comment: Are you talking about `<select>...</select>` for your list?

Comment: @Paul Sorry there was a formatting issue. It's using forEach.

Comment: Can't you use an attribute of TSName instead of using the index? And do in your loop, for example `<c:if test="${ TSName eq tool }"><p>This item is selected!</p></c:if>` ?

Comment: @Paul Thanks. I don't mind using it. But how do I get the exact selected items in the servlet from the jsp? There is further processing required with the selected items.

Comment: Did you put your `<form></form>` tags outside your forEach loop? If so, it means all inputs generated in your loop with the same name="" have the same form and parameters will be overriden.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Is there a work around?

Comment: Either use buttons, for example `<form><c:forEach items="${ TSName } var="TSName" varStatus="status">... <button type="submit" formaction="%yourFormURL%?tool=${ TSName }&url=${URL[status.index]}&uuid=${requestScope.uuid}" formmethod="">Proceed</button><c:forEach></form> ` or put your forms tags inside your forEach loop, at the beginning and at the end `<c:forEach><form>...</form></c:forEach>`. Note that when you use buttons the form action and method are passed by the button, not the form tag.

Comment: @Paul Thank you! It worked brilliantly. If you add you last comment as answer. I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: I can't since the question has been marked as duplicate. I suggest you to read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078701/how-do-i-pass-current-item-to-java-method-by-clicking-a-hyperlink-or-button-in-j) from BalusC as he has already handled this point.

Comment: I simply wasted my time reading that answer by him which has nothing to do with my question. I had updated my question stating that.