# How to handle button click on jsp list element in servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following situation:

There is my jsp file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>car.by</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editServlet">
<button type="submit">Редактировать(для админа)</button>
</form>
<form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
<button type="submit">Выйти</button>
</form>
<form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
    <tr>
        Марка <br>
        Коробка передач <br>
        Логин: <br>
        <button type="submit">Показать</button> <br>
    </tr>
</form>
<jsp:useBean id="cars" scope="request" type="java.util.List"/>
<c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <img SRC=${car.c_photo} width="250" height="250"> <br>
        Модель:<td>${car.c_model}</td><br>
        Цена за день:<td>${car.c_price}</td><br>
        Скидка:<td>${car.p_sale}</td><br>
        Производитель:<td>${car.c_producer}</td><br>
        Коробка передач:<td>${car.c_transmission}</td><br>
        Место нахождения:<td>${car.c_owner}</td><br>
        <form method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/reservationServlet">
            <button style="background-color: black" type="submit">Заказать</button>
        </form>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, here I have a list of forms. Each form has button. I don’t understand, how can I pass for example the car.c_model variable value from the jsp to servlet. Here is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/mainServlet")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private CarManager carManager = new CarManager();
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            List<Car> cars = carManager.getCarInfo();
            req.setAttribute("cars", cars);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("MainPage.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass current item to Java method by clicking a hyperlink or button in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078701/how-do-i-pass-current-item-to-java-method-by-clicking-a-hyperlink-or-button-in-j)