# Servlet doGet() doPost() method

Tags: servlets

Generally we specify the `doGet` and `doPost` in our HTML code, so that servlet will invoke these methods with respect to the call in HTML code.

Is there any way that whether we call `doPost` or `doGet` Servlet `doPost` method will get called?

I know there is one way that in `doGet` we can call `doPost` method , But apart from that is there any other method .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common method and put it into doGet() or doPost().

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
} 

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
} 

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling one from the other, or better - calling a 3rd method from both is the best approach.

You can override the `service()` method as well, but there's more code there that you might not want to loose.