# how does doPost request works?

Tags: java, http, servlets, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Servlets: doGet and doPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost)

I know `doGet()` request is appended to the request URL in a query string.But  I don't know the concept of `doPost()` request.how does `doPost` request posting information to the server.

Please Guide me to get the working concept of `doPost` request...

Comment: could you look at [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost)

Comment: you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2349741/420613

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post requests are used usually for sending data to Server, and get request for reading data from server. In Post request data is sent in http request body, so data size can be very large compared to Get. If a browser fires an POST request (usually a form submit) doPost of the mapping Servlet will be called. There is another overloaded method (service()) which is called for both GET and POST

Answer (score 1):

1. In `doPost()` the data is not appended in the URL.
2. It can handle large amount of data compared to the `doGet()` method.
3. Filling of form and submitting is done through `doPost()`, it's secure to use `doPost()` during submission of the username and password.
4. There is also differnce in the `doGet()` and `doPost()` header and body structure.

Answer (score 0):

`doGet()` can be used when client request doesn't intend to change stored data.

Answer (score 0):

The main conceptual  difference `GET` and `POST` is that, `GET` is used for getting the data from the server, and `POST` is used for updating the data to the server.

In general `POST` has the following properties:

- The data is `x-www-form-urlencoded` . Which means, the request parameters are sent as request body. And the server has to parse the request body for parameters.
- By default, when no content-length header is present, the default value for `GET` is 0 whereas for POST it is till end of stream.
- `GET` is `Idempotent` whereas `POST` is `Non-Idempotent`.  i.e, Proxies on failures for `GET` they retry. But, for `POST` they do not retry.