# pass values from jsp to servlet using <a href>

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, href

I have JSP page  -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
         <%
               String valueToPass = "Hello" ; 
         %>
    <a href="goToServlet...">Go to servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And servlet  -

```
    @WebServlet(name="/servlet123",
             urlPatterns={"/servlet123"})
    public class servlet123 extends HttpServlet {

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

        public void foo() {

        }
}
```

What should I write in `<a href="goToServlet...">Go to servlet</a>` in order to pass values (like `valueToPass` or maybe add the value as argument in the   ) to the `servlet123` ?

Can I invoke the specific method in `servlet123` (like `foo()`) using the link in the JSP?

**EDIT:**

How can I call servlet in URL? My pages hierarchy is like the following -

```
WebContent
 |-- JSPtest
 |    |-- callServletFromLink.jsp
 |-- WEB-INF
 :    :
```

And I want to call the `servlet123` in the folder src->control  .

I tried `<a href="servlet123">Go to servlet</a>` but it did not find the servlet when I press on the link.

**2nd EDIT:**

I tried `<a href="http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/servlet123">Go to servlet</a>` and it work  .

Comment: Remember to encode the value if needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to send parameters to the servlet using an URL, you should do it in this way

```
<a href="goToServlet?param1=value1&param2=value2">Go to servlet</a>
```

And then retrieve the values that will be available in the request.

Regarding your second question. I will say no. You can add a param in the URL, something like

```
<a href="goToServlet?method=methodName&param1=value1">Go to servlet</a>
```

And the use of that information to call a specific method.

By the way, if you use a framework like Struts, that will be easier since, in Struts, you can bound an URL to a specific Action method  (let's say "servlet")

**Edited**:

You have defined your servlet in this way:

```
@WebServlet("/servlet123")
```

You, your servlet will be available on /servlet123. See [doc](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations).

I have tested your code and it is working:

```
@WebServlet(name = "/servlet123", urlPatterns = { "/servlet123" })
public class Servlet123 extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h2>Hello Friends! Welcome to the world of servlet annotation </h2>");
        out.write("<br/>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Then, I called the servlet in `http://localhost:8080/myApp/servlet123` (being myApp your application context if you are using one).

Comment: thanks , so if I use use URL like "goToServlet?param1=value1&param2=value2" which method in the servlet will be invoked ? the doGet ?

Comment: You should use doGet. Take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2349741/980472

Comment: Then use request.getParameter("method") to get the value "methodName". You should url encode any parameter values, see [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). If within Java you can use the built in [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class.

Comment: @mrswadge I know about the encode   . I don't know how to call the servlet in URL   .

Comment: @jddsantaella I did it  , but the link not work ,I edited the post again.

Comment: is there a way to use this approach by calling several servlets ?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor I do no understand your question. You can build links that target different servlets

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="url">urltitle</a>` allows you to define a url. Calling a servlet from here is as good as calling it from a browser, just give the url as you would give it in browser to call the servlet like http://mysite.com?param1=val1&param2=val2 etc.

Comment: Now how do I retrieve the values of param1 and param2 in the second servlet?