# how to pass values from jsp to servlet through <a href> using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to send values from a jsp to the servlet via href.. but i dont know how to append the data.. pls use jstl tags only no servlets pls... 
i checked this [pass values from jsp to servlet using <a href>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840751/pass-values-from-jsp-to-servlet-using-a-href) but they utilize scriplets..

```
 <tr div class="even">
<td style="font-size:14px;"> 
    <a href="/myproject/s/permanentUserAuctionHistory?aid=" <c:out value="${auctionDo.auctionId}"/>>
    <c:out value="${auctionDo.auctionId}"/> </a></td>
```

Comment: whats wrong? are you not able to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quote (") after `aid=` inside the `href` attribute breaks the `href`.

You can just use JSTL

```
<a href="/myproject/s/permanentUserAuctionHistory?aid=${auctionDo.auctionId}">
    <c:out value="${auctionDo.auctionId}"/> 
</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="/myproject/s/permanentUserAuctionHistory?aid=${auctionDo.auctionId}">
    ${auctionDo.auctionId} 
</a>
```

Comment: thank you Aniket.. the first one worked.. so here we are just calling the value.. my mistake was displaying the value.. rt??

Comment: @user3214173 : You are welcome :). There was `"` issue and yes `<c:out ..... />` is like using expression `<%=..... %>`.