# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: servlets, http-get, http-status-code-405

The code below is from a book,so it'll not be incorrect.But I don't know how to solve this below error.When delete the method doGet(),the same error!

**"HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override 
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws IOException,ServletException{
    this.doPost(request,response);
}
@Override 
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                                   throws IOException,ServletException{
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletOutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
    File pdf=null;
    BufferedInputStream buf=null;
    try{
        pdf=new File("C:\\Users\\lk\\Desktop\\Desktop\\ example.pdf");
        response.setContentLength((int)pdf.length());
        FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(pdf);
        buf=new BufferedInputStream(input);
        int readBytes=0;
        while((readBytes=buf.read())!=-1)    out.write(readBytes);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("file not found!");
    }finally{
        if(out!=null) out.close();
        if(buf!=null) buf.close();
    }
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<web-app xsi:.........." version="2.5"> 
-<servlet> 
<description>This is the description of my Java EE component</description> 
<display-name>This is the display name of my Java EE component</display-name> 
<servlet-name>PDFServlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>PDFServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
-<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>PDFServlet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/PDFServlet</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
-<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list> 
-<login-config> 
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method> 
</login-config> 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Servlet code seems correct.
Provide `web.xml` entry and Servlet calling URL.

There are two main reasons which cause this error:

1) You do not have a valid doGet() method, when you type the servlet’s path in address bar directly, the web container like Tomcat will try to invoke the doGet() method.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
....
}
```

2) You made a HTTP post request from a HTML form, but you do not have a doPost() method to handle it. The doGet() can not handle the “Post” request.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
....
}
```

Read @BalusC's answer for more details. : [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost)

Comment: Servlet calling URL:"http://localhost:8080/Test/PDFServlet" (Test:the project's name)

Comment: Now i don't know,but a new problem occur:in the myeclipse window,output is always:"file not found!",why? my path of file is right.

Comment: I solved the problem,thanks a lot! finally,it is the problem about the server,i'll take care of it.

Comment: Good to hear that the problem is resolved. You are wel-cpome

Comment: @itzyjr so what was the problem?

Answer (score 14):

I had this same problem just now. "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL". My solution was as follows:

```
public abstract class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected HttpServletRequest req;
    protected HttpServletResponse resp;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.req = req;
        this.resp = resp;
        this.requestManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.req = req;
        this.resp = resp;
        this.requestManager();

    }

    protected abstract void requestManager() throws IOException;
}
```

I had problem in my constructor, because the "doGet" I was calling the super

Comment: This one is what caught me - I thought that when overriding a method it was standard practice to call the parent's method. Calling super.doGet(req, resp) caused this error. (drove me crazy because a break point in my doGet was hit... then the server would respond with the 405.. despite the fact I was explicitly setting the status)

Answer (score -1):

Replace the line

```
pdf=new File("C:\\Users\\lk\\Desktop\\Desktop\\ example.pdf");
```

with

```
pdf=new File("C:/Users/lk/Desktop/Desktop/example.pdf");
```

and then proceed again.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do

```
<form action="servlet name " method="post">
```

in your index.jsp file

Answer (score -1):

When the above error appears then override `doGet()` method.

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using html file. To create web page.
So when I encountered with this error. My solution was:
Just to remove  " index.html " path in my web.xml file.
becayse my html file name was the same as "index.html"

Answer (score -3):

Each servlet must contain a doGet() method, which is defaultly executed by server.
so see that you have doGet method.

Comment: no they don't. If you plan on supporting GET requests using standard servlet interface then yes, but you don't have to do that.