# Servlet within a list within a jsp file

Tags: javascript, html, list, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to link a servlet within a list within a .jsp file  ?

```
<form>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="HomeClientServlet">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="TransactionsServlet">Transactions</a></li>
    <li><a href="StartTransferServlet">Transfer</a></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

The upper code wont work and im not sure how to do this.

*NOTE - The servlet needs to run doPost and not doGet.

As Jigar Joshi said I have tried to do this:

It didnt work and then i tried doing this instead:

```
    <form>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="current"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/HomeClientServlet">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/TransactionsServlet">Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/StartTransferServlet">Transfer</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

This one is invalid

```
<form>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/HomeClientServlet" method="POST"><input type="submit">Home</form></li>
</ul></form>
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/servlets-doget-and-dopost and you'll have a better idea of what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

clicking on valid anchor by default makes a GET request, if you want to make a POST instead then either write javascript to handle on click and make POST or place a tiny form instead of anchor

replace `anchor` tag with something like below

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/TransactionsServlet" method="POST">
  <input type="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to change or make POST ? 
Like in code cause im not sure I understand what you meant

Comment: Its invalid to put form inside li tag

Comment: remove li then or [write javascript to make post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: If I remove li tag then this thread is obsolete cause the whole point was to make the <li> link to servlet doPost. 
I could remove the li tag but then I stand without a nav bar. 
And javascript is not my stongest language.
But thanks for the try

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
    < form method="post" action="<%=application.getContextPath()%>/Controller">
    < ul>
    < li> < a href="javascript:callController()"> Controller < /a> < /li>
    < /ul>
```

And in the script part

```
function callController()
{
   ------- whatever be you want to do....
}
```